# C# Асинхронный TCP сервер, как отследить закрытые соединения от клиента?

Tags: c#, tcp, сокеты

Вот пример от MSDN:

```
using System;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Net.Sockets;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading;  

// State object for reading client data asynchronously  
public class StateObject {  
    // Client  socket.  
    public Socket workSocket = null;  
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;  
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];  
// Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
}  

public class AsynchronousSocketListener {  
    // Thread signal.  
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);  

    public AsynchronousSocketListener() {  
    }  

    public static void StartListening() {  
        // Data buffer for incoming data.  
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];  

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.  
        // The DNS name of the computer  
        // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".  
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());  
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];  
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);  

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,  
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );  

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.  
        try {  
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);  
            listener.Listen(100);  

            while (true) {  
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
                allDone.Reset();  

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");  
                listener.BeginAccept(   
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),  
                    listener );  

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
                allDone.WaitOne();  
            }  

        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");  
        Console.Read();  

    }  

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {  
        // Signal the main thread to continue.  
        allDone.Set();  

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
        Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;  
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);  

        // Create the state object.  
        StateObject state = new StateObject();  
        state.workSocket = handler;  
        handler.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,  
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);  
    }  

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {  
        String content = String.Empty;  

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;  
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;  

        // Read data from the client socket.   
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);  

        if (bytesRead > 0) {  
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(  
                state.buffer,0,bytesRead));  

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read   
            // more data.  
            content = state.sb.ToString();  
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) {  
                // All the data has been read from the   
                // client. Display it on the console.  
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",  
                    content.Length, content );  
                // Echo the data back to the client.  
                Send(handler, content);  
            } else {  
                // Not all data received. Get more.  
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,  
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data) {  
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);  

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,  
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);  
    }  

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {  
        try {  
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket handler = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;  

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);  
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);  

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);  
            handler.Close();  

        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  

    public static int Main(String[] args) {  
        StartListening();  
        return 0;  
    }  
}
```

Можно ли сделать callback и узнать когда с клиентом нет связи?

Comment: Зачем вы используете снипеты для кода на C#? В браузере можно запустить только код на javascript...

Answer (score 1):

```
if (bytesRead > 0) {  
// ...
}
else {
  CloseClientSocket(handler);
}


public void CloseClientSocket(Socket handler) {
  try {
    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
  }
  catch (Exception) { }
  handler.Close();
  connections = connections - 1;
}
```

Comment: Стоило бы написать к коду какие-нибудь пояснения...

Answer (score 0):

```
TcpClient client;

// TODO other code

// Проверяем наличие подключения.
if (client.Client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
{
    if (client.Client.Receive(new byte[1], SocketFlags.Peek) == 0) throw new SocketException((int)SocketError.ConnectionReset);
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214630/373567 вот поновее пример. Там где я пишу в консоль разные события, можно вызывать колбэки.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

**1.** Ловить SocketException:[image: screen]

```
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    String content = String.Empty;
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    try
    {
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            Console.WriteLine($"Сообщение: {state.sb.ToString()}");
        }

        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
        handler.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**2.** Проверять количество полученных байтов:

```
if (bytesRead > 0)
{
    // do something
} else {
    // connection closed
}
```

**P.S:** [документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145145(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown
>   method, and all available data has been received, the EndReceive
>   method will complete immediately and return zero bytes.

Перевод:

> Если удаленный узел закрывает Socket соединение с методом Shutdown, и
>   все доступные данные были получены, то метод EndReceive немедленно
>   завершится и вернет 0 байт.

Comment: У меня получилось уже сделать это но чесно говоря я не понимаю как оно работает

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ

Comment: Я не знаю как, но этот else работает когда клиент disconnect (помните предыдущий пример от MSDN? там к-во клиентов примерно так работало)

Comment: И мне теперь интересно что происходит с bytesread

Comment: Если клиент ничего не отправляет, то там должен быть 0 какбы, но там 0 или меньше 0 когда он прерывает конект

Comment: кстати как работает @ и никнейм здесь? Вы сами пишете или автоматом как-нибудь можно?

Comment: @A Увы нету уведомлений от клиента, мне интересно каким образом работает мой ответ (который я вырезал с прежнего примера от MSDN :))

Comment: Что происходит с bytesread когда клиент ничего не отправляет и когда он прерывает соединение?

Comment: Ясно, спасибо, а если не отправлять сообщений всеравно идет обмен байтами? Если есть коннект только к-во байт > 0?

Comment: Проверки свойств Connected и Available - лишние. Правильно проверять только количество пришедших байт. Это же стандартная проверка для любых потоковых данных...

Comment: @AresGod те со стороны сервера disconnect можно делать только после ReadCallback?

Comment: @MikeWaters, обновил ответ. См. код после скриншота.

Comment: @AresGod, ясно понял, через Exception тоже можно значит, просто не очень люблю их использовать