# TcpListener - как реализовать HTTP сервер и подключиться к нему клиентом

Tags: c#, http, tcplistener

Есть программа(там server) при подключении к которому  он в консоль выдаёт адреса порты..ю(это не важно)
Нужно программу разбить на две, что был запуск server'а, а потом к нему подключился client.
Не совсем понял, как это должно реализоваться.

1. запуск сервера
2. далее клиент к нему подключается

т.е. два  решения

*Типо некоторые классы надо разбить на client и server? Вроде и так все разбито.*

Вот **важная часть**, наверное по итогу с самим запуском (наверное, каким то образом особенным надо запустить, я не понимаю) (1) и подключением client'a к нему, тож с помощью методов каких то, наверное (2).

Вот код:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Server(8999);
        }
    }

    public class Server
    {
        TcpListener Listener;
        public Server(int Port)
        {
            Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
            //запустили прослушивание на подключения клиентов
            Listener.Start();


            while (true)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ClientThread), Listener.AcceptTcpClient());
            }
        }

        static void ClientThread(Object StateInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new Client();
                client.ClientRun((TcpClient)StateInfo);
            }
            catch
            {
                ((TcpClient)StateInfo).Close();
            }
        }

        ~Server()
        {
            if (Listener != null)
            {
                Listener.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Client
    {
        const int MAX_LENGTH_HEADER = 8192;

        private void SendError(TcpClient Client, int Code)
        {
            string CodeStr = Code.ToString() + " " + ((HttpStatusCode)Code).ToString();
            string Html = "<html><body><h1>" + CodeStr + "</h1></body></html>";
            string Str = "HTTP/1.1 " + CodeStr + "\nContent-type: text/html\nContent-Length:" + Html.Length.ToString() + "\n\n" + Html;
            byte[] Buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Str);
            Client.GetStream().Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
            Client.Close();
        }

        public void ClientRun(TcpClient Client)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string IP = client.DownloadString("http://api.ipify.org");
            Console.WriteLine("Подключение произошло по IP: " + IP);
           
            Console.WriteLine("IP: " + "{1} : {0} Connect OK","Data: " + DateTime.Now, Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Порт" + ((IPEndPoint)Client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port.ToString());

            string Request = "";
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[8192];
            int Count;
            while ((Count = Client.GetStream().Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                Request += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Buffer, 0, Count);

                if (!Request.Contains("POST"))
                {
                    if (Request.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n") >= 0 || Request.Length > MAX_LENGTH_HEADER)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", Request.Split(' ').Take(2)));
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Request.Split(new string[] { "\r\n\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Count() > 1 || Request.Length > MAX_LENGTH_HEADER)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", Request.Split(' ').Take(2)));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            var RequestUri = Request.RegexParse(@"^\w+\s+([^\s]+)[^\s]*\s+HTTP/.*|").Split(' ').FirstOrDefault(x => x[0] == '/');

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestUri))
            {
                SendError(Client, 400);
                return;
            }

            RequestUri = Uri.UnescapeDataString(RequestUri);

            if (RequestUri.IndexOf("..") >= 0)
            {
                SendError(Client, 400);
                return;
            }

            if (RequestUri.Length > 0)
            {
                var split = RequestUri.Split('?').ToList();

                if (Request.Contains("POST"))
                {
                    var postData = Request.Split(new string[] { "\r\n\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    split.Insert(1, postData[1]);
                }

                var resultString = "Hello. Gg "; //Формируем ответ
                
                Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
                
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultString))
                {
                    SendError(Client, 404);
                    return;
                }

                string Headers = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-Length: " + resultString.Length + "\n\n";
                byte[] HeadersBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Headers);
                Client.GetStream().Write(HeadersBuffer, 0, HeadersBuffer.Length);
                using (var reader = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resultString.ToString())))
                {
                    while (reader.Position < reader.Length)
                    {
                        Count = reader.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
                        Client.GetStream().Write(Buffer, 0, Count);
                    }
                    Client.Close();
                }
            }
            Client.Close();
        }
    }

    public static class ext
    {
        public static string RegexParse(this string data, string pattern)
        {
            var result = "";

            var regex = new Regex(pattern);
            if (regex.IsMatch(data)) result = regex.Match(data).ToString();

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пишете, что используете C#8, а на деле используете уйму древних подходов и технологий (`WebClient` например). К чему тогда тут эта метка?

Comment: У вас клиент стартует внутри класса Server в методе `static void ClientThread(Object StateInfo)`, по всей видимости такой сцепленный запуск не подходит, надо отцепить запуск клиента и сделать его отдельным.

Comment: @Bulson, кто то писал, что нужно сделать так:
Код сервера - одно консольное приложение.
Код клиента - второе консольное приложение.
Если у меня просто получится отцепить запуск? сойдёт?ибо я не понимаю, что нужно уже с кодом делать

Comment: @Bulson не подскажите как мой кад разделить на два? Сколько пробую не получается, все время проблемы с ссылками, независимо сделать не могу.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot Да, спасибо вам большое!!!!

Comment: @Bulson извините, что пишу здесь, не знаете как на подключение и отключение каждого клиента сделать стабильный подсчёт - "в сети".на данный момент так.
--т.е если 1 чел он выводит сразу:
===1 в сети,
2 в сети===
---при подключении 2го тоже самое---.
При отключении стабильный подсчет на - типо в сети 1 если один пользователь отключился, если 2 отключилось - 0, Но это сопутствуется сообщением "подключился клиент" этого не надо...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вообще написать с нуля свой HTTP сервер - не так то просто. Но сама архитектура сервера очень простая:

- Создаем `TcpListener`.
- Просим у него подождать и отдать нам подключившегося клиента `AcceptTcpClient()`.
- Он отдает нам `TcpClient`, который предоставляет заветный `NetworkStream`, в который можно писать, и из которого можно читать, до тех пор пока соединение не будет разорвано.
- И таких соединений может быть одновременно сколько угодно, поэтому мне пришло на помощь [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

#### Управление сервером

Запуск сервера будет выглядеть так

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (HttpServer server = new HttpServer(8080)) // порт 8080
        {
            Task servertask = server.ListenAsync();
            while (true)
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input == "stop")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Остановка сервера...");
                    server.Stop();
                    break;
                }
            }
            await servertask;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу для выхода...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Где `HttpServer` - наш класс сервера, где живет `TcpListener`. Здесь все просто, запускаем сервер - читаем консоль на случай, если пользователь что-то введет, и если он ввел `stop`, вызываем остановку сервера. Готово.

#### Сервер

Сам сервер посложнее, и уже зависит от реализации клиента. Вот код, который отвечает за прослушивание порта и cоздание `TcpClient` в любых количествах, а так же следит, чтобы всех клиентов можно было правильно погасить, если сервер надо будет выключить. Без зависаний и конфликтов.

*Я в курсе про существование класса `HttpListener`, и знаю, что с помощью него можно всё сделать в 10 раз проще, но здесь задача именно написать свой велосипед в обучающих целях.*

```cs
class HttpServer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TcpListener _listener;
    private readonly List<HttpServerClient> _clients;

    public HttpServer(int port)
    {
        _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        _clients = new List<HttpServerClient>();
    }

    public async Task ListenAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            _listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Сервер стартовал на " + _listener.LocalEndpoint);
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Подключение: " + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint + " > " + client.Client.LocalEndPoint);
                lock (_clients)
                {
                    _clients.Add(new HttpServerClient(client, c => { lock (_clients) { _clients.Remove(c); } c.Dispose(); }));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
        {
            if (ex.ObjectName.EndsWith("Socket"))
                Console.WriteLine("Сервер остановлен.");
            else 
                throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _listener.Stop();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    bool disposed;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(typeof(HttpServer).FullName);
        disposed = true;
        _listener.Stop();
        if (disposing)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Отключаю подключенных клиентов...");
            lock (_clients)
            {
                foreach (HttpServerClient client in _clients)
                {
                    client.Dispose();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Клиенты отключены.");
        }
    }

    ~HttpServer() => Dispose(false);
}
```

#### Реализация HTTP протокола и взаимодействие с браузером

А вот вторая часть вашей задачи сложнее - реализация HTTP протокола.

*Давайте сразу условимся, что здесь клиент пользователя - это браузер, а не просто приложение на базе `HttpClient`, которое вы сами написали. Какой смысл реализовывать HTTP протокол, который будет не совместим с браузером, правда?*

Казалось бы, что там сложного?

Пришло

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

В ответ отправить

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

И готово

А вот и нет! Не так все просто. Если вы сделаете так, как я выше написал, браузер будет висеть в ожидании данных до тех пор, пока соединение не будет принудительно разорвано либо сервером, либо по таймауту (ну или операционной системой).

Починить это не сложно, добавить в ответ HTTP заголовок `Content-Length: 0`. Ура, браузер получил белую страничку, и успокоился. Но что делать, если браузеру хочется отправить HTML страничку. Обычно браузер при первом подключении к серверу отправляет 2 запроса `GET /` и `GET /favicon.ico`. Эти запросы как-то надо различать.

А еще браузер присылает заголовок `Connection: keep-alive`, бывает еще `close`, от этого зависит поведение сервера. Во втором случае надо закрыть соединение, а в первом - ждать следующий пакет от браузера в этом же соединении. Ух, сколько всего, а ведь я еще только начал.

**В итоге, сама реализация HTTP протокола заключается в способности сервера парсить HTTP заголовки запроса и формировать вменяемый ответ по тем же правилам.**

Руками [вот это вот всё](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) реализовать сложновато. Но есть же великолепный `HttpClient`, который уже все умеет, особенно парсить HTTP заголовки. Надо бы позаимствовать готовенькое. Нет, не скопировать код с .NET гитхаба, а использовать те самые 2 класса `HttpRequestMessage` и `HttpResponseMessage`, которые по своей сути являются контейнерами для HTTP заголовков и содержат в себе контент, точнее `NetworkStream`, содержащий контент. Так и поступим.

Вот само сердце серверной части, которая общается с браузером.

```cs
class HttpServerClient : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TcpClient _client;
    private readonly NetworkStream _stream;
    private readonly EndPoint _remoteEndPoint;
    private readonly Task _clientTask;
    private readonly Action<HttpServerClient> _disposeCallback;

    public HttpServerClient(TcpClient client, Action<HttpServerClient> disposeCallback)
    {
        _client = client;
        _stream = client.GetStream();
        _remoteEndPoint = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
        _disposeCallback = disposeCallback;
        _clientTask = RunReadingLoop();
    }

    const string errorTemplate = "<html><head><title>{0}</title></head><body><center><h1>{0}</h1></center><hr><center>TcpListener server</center></body></html>";

    private async Task RunReadingLoop()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                (HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode status) = await ReceivePacket().ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (request != null)
                    Console.WriteLine($"<< {request.Method.Method} {request.RequestUri}");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine($"<< ??");
                //Console.WriteLine(request);
                using HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(status);
                if (request != null)
                    foreach (var c in request?.Headers.Connection)
                        response.Headers.Connection.Add(c);
                else
                    response.Headers.Connection.Add("close");
                if (status == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    if (request.RequestUri.ToString() == "/")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(">> /");
                        response.Content = CreateHtmlContent($"<html><head><title>Главная страница</title></head><body>Привет, {_remoteEndPoint}!</body></html>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                        Console.WriteLine($">> {(int)response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                        response.Content = CreateHtmlContent(string.Format(errorTemplate, $"{(int)response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase}"));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($">> {(int)response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                    response.Content = CreateHtmlContent(string.Format(errorTemplate, $"{(int)response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase}"));
                }
                // Console.WriteLine(response);
                await SendResponse(response).ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (response.Headers.Connection.Contains("close"))
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Подключение к " + _remoteEndPoint + " закрыто клиентом.");
            _stream.Close();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Подключение к " + _remoteEndPoint + " разорвано клиентом.");
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Подключение к " + _remoteEndPoint + " закрыто сервером.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType().Name + ": " + ex.Message);
        }
        if (!disposed)
            _disposeCallback(this);
    }

    private HttpContent CreateHtmlContent(string text)
    {
        StringContent content = new StringContent(text, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");
        content.Headers.ContentLength = content.Headers.ContentLength;
        return content;
    }

    private async Task SendResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_stream, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            sw.WriteLine($"HTTP/{response.Version} {(int)response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase}");
            sw.Write(response.Headers);
            sw.WriteLine(response.Content?.Headers.ToString() ?? "");
        }
        if (response.Content != null)
            await response.Content.CopyToAsync(_stream);
    }

    private async Task<(HttpRequestMessage, HttpStatusCode)> ReceivePacket()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            string requestHeader = await ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            string[] headerTokens = requestHeader.Split(" ");
            if (headerTokens.Length != 3)
                return (null, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            request.Method = new HttpMethod(headerTokens[0]);
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(headerTokens[1], UriKind.Relative);
            string[] protocolTokens = headerTokens[2].Split('/');
            if (protocolTokens.Length != 2 || protocolTokens[0] != "HTTP")
                return (null, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            request.Version = Version.Parse(protocolTokens[1]);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            HttpContent content = new StreamContent(ms);
            request.Content = content;
            while (true)
            {
                string headerLine = await ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (headerLine.Length == 0)
                    break;
                string[] tokens = headerLine.Split(":", 2);
                if (tokens.Length == 2)
                {
                    foreach (HttpRequestHeader h in Enum.GetValues(typeof(HttpRequestHeader)))
                    {
                        if (tokens[0].ToLower() == h.GetName().ToLower())
                        {
                            if ((int)h >= 10 && (int)h <= 19) // if Entity Header
                                request.Content.Headers.Add(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
                            else
                                request.Headers.Add(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            long length = request.Content.Headers?.ContentLength ?? 0;

            if (length > 0)
            {
                await CopyBytesAsync(_stream, ms, (int)length);
                ms.Position = 0;
            }
            return (request, HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch
        {
            return (null, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }

    private async Task CopyBytesAsync(Stream source, Stream target, int count)
    {
        const int bufferSize = 65536;
        byte[] buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(bufferSize);
        try
        {
            while (count > 0)
            {
                int bytesReceived = await source.ReadAsync(buffer.AsMemory(0, Math.Min(count, bufferSize)));
                if (bytesReceived == 0)
                    break;
                await target.WriteAsync(buffer.AsMemory(0, bytesReceived));
                count -= bytesReceived;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> ReadLineAsync() => await Task.Run(ReadLine);

    private string ReadLine()
    {
        LineState lineState = LineState.None;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
        while (true)
        {
            int b = _stream.ReadByte();
            switch (b)
            {
                case -1:
                    throw new HttpRequestException("Подключение разорвано.");
                case '\r':
                    if (lineState == LineState.None)
                        lineState = LineState.CR;
                    else
                        throw new ProtocolViolationException("Неожиданный CR в заголовке запроса.");
                    break;
                case '\n':
                    if (lineState == LineState.CR)
                        lineState = LineState.LF;
                    else
                        throw new ProtocolViolationException("Неожиданный LF в заголовке запроса.");
                    break;
                default:
                    lineState = LineState.None;
                    sb.Append((char)b);
                    break;
            }
            if (lineState == LineState.LF)
                break;
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    bool disposed;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(typeof(HttpServer).FullName);
        disposed = true;
        if (_client.Connected)
        {
            _stream.Close();
            _clientTask.Wait();
        }
        if (disposing)
        {
            _client.Dispose();
        }
    }

    ~HttpServerClient() => Dispose(false);
}
```

*Меньше кода не получилось, уж простите. Не хотелось пилить минимальное решение на костылях, ибо таких решений в интернете можно найти навалом.*

И еще немного впомогательного кода, который я утащил с [.NET гитхаба](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Net.WebHeaderCollection/src/System/Net/HttpRequestHeader.cs). И в конце еще маленькое перечисление.

```cs
internal static class HttpRequestHeaderExtensions
{
    private static readonly string[] s_names = {
        "Cache-Control",
        "Connection",
        "Date",
        "Keep-Alive",
        "Pragma",
        "Trailer",
        "Transfer-Encoding",
        "Upgrade",
        "Via",
        "Warning",
        "Allow",
        "Content-Length",
        "Content-Type",
        "Content-Encoding",
        "Content-Language",
        "Content-Location",
        "Content-MD5",
        "Content-Range",
        "Expires",
        "Last-Modified",
        "Accept",
        "Accept-Charset",
        "Accept-Encoding",
        "Accept-Language",
        "Authorization",
        "Cookie",
        "Expect",
        "From",
        "Host",
        "If-Match",
        "If-Modified-Since",
        "If-None-Match",
        "If-Range",
        "If-Unmodified-Since",
        "Max-Forwards",
        "Proxy-Authorization",
        "Referer",
        "Range",
        "Te",
        "Translate",
        "User-Agent",
    };

    public static string GetName(this HttpRequestHeader header)
    {
        return s_names[(int)header];
    }
}

enum LineState
{
    None,
    LF,
    CR    
}
```

#### Запуск и использование сервера

Собственно, вот скриншот браузера FireFox, говорящий сам за себя.

[image: firefox server test]

Я сделал скриншот, и затем остановил сервер командой `stop`.

Вывод в консоль

```
Сервер стартовал на 0.0.0.0:8080
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64599 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
<< GET /favicon.ico
>> 404 Not Found
stop
Остановка сервера...
Сервер остановлен.
Отключаю подключенных клиентов...
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64599 закрыто сервером.
Клиенты отключены.
Нажмите любую клавишу для выхода...
```

Вот и всё, спасибо за внимание.

---

**P.S.** Что будет, если я зажму клавишу <kbd>F5</kbd> в FireFox, а вот что.

```
Сервер стартовал на 0.0.0.0:8080
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64940 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
<< GET /
>> /
<< GET /
>> /
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64942 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64943 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64944 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64945 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64946 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64943 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64940 закрыто сервером.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64942 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64947 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64948 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64949 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64950 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64951 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64952 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64944 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64953 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64945 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64946 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64954 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
<< GET /
<< GET /
>> /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64947 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64955 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64948 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64956 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64949 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64950 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64957 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64958 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64951 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64959 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64952 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64953 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64960 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64961 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
<< GET /
<< GET /
<< GET /
>> /
>> /
>> /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64962 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64958 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64955 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64963 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64964 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64959 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64956 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64965 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64954 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64957 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64966 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64960 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64967 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64968 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64961 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
<< GET /
<< GET /
>> /
>> /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64969 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64970 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64962 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64964 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64963 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64965 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64966 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64971 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64967 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64972 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64973 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
<< GET /
>> /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64974 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64968 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64971 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64975 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64969 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64970 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64976 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64972 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64977 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64978 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64979 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64980 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64973 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
<< GET /
<< GET /
>> /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64981 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64974 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64982 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64983 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64977 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64976 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64975 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64984 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64985 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64986 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64987 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64988 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64989 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64979 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64990 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64980 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64978 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64983 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64981 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64991 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64982 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64992 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64984 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64993 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64988 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64985 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64986 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64994 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64987 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64995 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64990 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64996 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64989 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64997 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64998 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64991 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:64999 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64992 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64993 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64994 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65000 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65002 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64996 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65003 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65004 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64995 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64997 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65005 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65006 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65007 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64998 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65008 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65009 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65000 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:64999 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65010 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65011 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65002 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65012 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65004 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65003 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65006 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65013 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65005 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65014 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65015 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65016 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65007 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65017 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65008 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65018 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65011 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65009 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65019 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65010 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65020 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65012 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65021 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
<< GET /
<< GET /
>> /
>> /
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65022 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65014 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65023 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65015 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65016 разорвано клиентом.
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65024 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65017 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65018 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65013 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65025 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65019 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65026 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65027 > 127.0.0.1:8080
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65028 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65029 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
<< GET /
<< GET /
>> /
>> /
>> /
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65030 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65031 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65020 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65032 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65024 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65022 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65021 разорвано клиентом.
>> /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65023 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65026 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65025 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65027 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
<< GET /
>> /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65028 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65029 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65031 разорвано клиентом.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65030 разорвано клиентом.
<< GET /
>> /
stop
Остановка сервера...
Сервер остановлен.
Отключаю подключенных клиентов...
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65032 закрыто сервером.
Клиенты отключены.
Нажмите любую клавишу для выхода...
```

Где же запросы к `favicon.ico`? А браузер закешировал предыдущий ответ, и повторно запрос не отправляет. Но можно принудительно через <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>. В любом случае, здесь по номерам портов отчетливо видно, что часть запросов обрабатывается параллельно.

**Бонус:** запасливый новый Microsoft Edge устанавливает сразу 3 подключения. Почему не 1 и не 5 - не понятно. Видимо у Microsoft свои взгляды на то, как использовать сокеты.

```
Сервер стартовал на 0.0.0.0:8080
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65090 > 127.0.0.1:8080
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65091 > 127.0.0.1:8080
<< GET /
>> /
<< GET /favicon.ico
>> 404 Not Found
Подключение: 127.0.0.1:65092 > 127.0.0.1:8080
stop
Остановка сервера...
Сервер остановлен.
Отключаю подключенных клиентов...
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65090 закрыто сервером.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65091 закрыто сервером.
Подключение к 127.0.0.1:65092 закрыто сервером.
Клиенты отключены.
Нажмите любую клавишу для выхода...
```

Comment: А почему не HttpListener? Чтобы не заниматься разбором http-request'а и раутингом вручную

Comment: @VladD я об этом написал в ответе :) Второй абзац после заголовка "Сервер".

Comment: Точно, только сейчас заметил