# TcpChat (Console)

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

Нужно сделать tcp чат, есть сервер и несколько клиентов, сообщения отправляются на сервер и потом к клиенту. Проблема такая: сейчас все сообщение клиентов отправляются на сервер (смт. фото), как сделать отправку сообщений с сервера клиенту?[image]

Server:

```
class Client 
{
   public TcpClient tcpClient;

    public void loadClient()
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());
        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        string massage = reader.ReadLine();
        string userName = massage;

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome " + userName);

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                massage = reader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(userName + ": " + massage);
                massage += "\n";

                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(massage);
                networkStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            catch 
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        tcpClient.Close();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPAddress iPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        TcpListener clientListener = new TcpListener(iPAddress, 34561);

        try
        {
            clientListener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Connect...");

            while (true)
            {

                TcpClient tcpClient = clientListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Client client = new Client();
                client.tcpClient = tcpClient;

                Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(client.loadClient));
                thread.Start();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            clientListener.Stop();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        try
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 34561);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());
            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            string dataToSend = name + "\n";

            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToSend);
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write(name + ": ");
                dataToSend = Console.ReadLine() + "\n";

                data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToSend);
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Это учебное задание? Обязательно использовать `TcpListener`+`TcpClient`?

Comment: Если кратко, сервер не предназначен для отправки сообщений, он ничего не должен отправлять от своего имени. А вот клиенты должны иметь возможность друг с другом переписываться. Задача сервера - это только прием и доставка сообщений, ну и управление подключениями. Вам стоит переосмыслить эту задачу.

Comment: @aepot учебное, не обязательно, это я так реализовал, вы правильно поняли: должна быть возможность переписываться друг с другом, все таки сервер же должен принять сообщение и доставить конкретному пользователю  - вот именно это и не могу реализовать, сейчас же сообщения доставляются серверу только

Comment: Правильно использовать `TcpListener` [не так просто](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214630/373567), но если хочется, можете выкинуть из того решения HTTP часть и реализовать чат-комнату на базе того движка, во всяком случае класс `HttpServer` и метод `Main` вообще не изменятся, его достаточно только переименовать. А с клиентом все просто: отправляем текст и слушаем текст. Быть может завтра попробую написать решение, например на базе `HttpListener`+`WebSocket` ([грубый пример](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bhushanbhure/websocket-server-using-httplistener-and-client-with-client/))

Comment: @aepot Если писать на базе HttpListener+WebSocket то трудно будет для восприятия и понимания что происходит, тут для начала хоть разобраться с обычным Socket и TcpListener

Comment: А вот это весьма спорный вопрос. Я вам ссылку на "не так просто" дал, там как раз скелет для чата на базе `TcpListener`, во всяком случае управление подключениями там сделано нормально. Я пишу потихоньку решение, но получается не быстро, да и времени не так на это много, а хочется сделать как раз простой для понимания пример, так что как будет готово, так опубликую. Пишу и как раз сам разбираюсь с вебсокетами.

Comment: @aepot да, смотрел пример, вполне  отличный но мне не нужно на столько глобальный чат, это все таки учебное задание, хотя и из того примера можно что то взять

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Писать чат, так по-взрослому. Давайте сразу использовать уже разработанные протоколы для общения клиент-сервер, а не слать байты на низком уровне. Это неудобно, получится очень много кода, и чтобы дописать решение до вменяемого уровня, придется реализовать свой протокол, который будет отказоустойчивым как уже существующие.

### WebSocket чат

Решение получилось не маленькое, на базе `HttpListener`+`WebSocket` для сервера, и на базе `ClientWebSocket` для клиента. Но и я бы не сказал, что оно непостижимо сложное. Сложность восприятия зависит от ваших знаний и стремления разобраться.

### Технологии

Чтобы работать с сетью, нужно либо быть виртуозом при работе с потоками `Thread`, потому что с ними управиться не так то просто, либо использовать асинхронность, а в случае с `WebSocket` - вообще вариант только один. Если вы не знакомы с асинхронным программированием с использованием ключевых слов `async` и `await`, обязательно от начала и до конца внимательно прочитайте эту статью: [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

### Клиент

**Program.cs**

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите имя: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        ClientWebSocket ws = new ClientWebSocket();
        ws.Options.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name), string.Empty);
        await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://localhost:8080/ws/"), CancellationToken.None);
        Console.WriteLine("Соединение установлено");
        Task receciveTask = ReceiveAsync(ws);
        while (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            string message = Console.ReadLine();
            if (message == "exit" || ws.State != WebSocketState.Open)
                break;
            if (message.Length > 0)
                await SendAsync(ws, message);
        }
        if (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            await CloseAsync(ws);
        await receciveTask;
        Console.WriteLine("Соединение закрыто");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static Task SendAsync(ClientWebSocket ws, string message)
    {
        return ws.SendAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    private static Task CloseAsync(ClientWebSocket ws)
    {
        return ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    private static async Task ReceiveAsync(ClientWebSocket ws)
    {
        Memory<byte> buffer = new byte[1024];
        List<byte> data = new List<byte>();
        while (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            ValueWebSocketReceiveResult wsResult = await ws.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
            switch (wsResult.MessageType)
            {
                case WebSocketMessageType.Close when ws.State == WebSocketState.CloseReceived:
                    await CloseAsync(ws);
                    Console.WriteLine($"WebSocket закрыт сервером, нажмите Enter для выхода...");
                    break;
                case WebSocketMessageType.Close:
                    Console.WriteLine($"WebSocket закрыт клиентом");
                    break;
                case WebSocketMessageType.Text:
                    data.AddRange(buffer[..wsResult.Count].ToArray());
                    if (wsResult.EndOfMessage)
                    {
                        string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data.ToArray());
                        Console.WriteLine(text);
                        data.Clear();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine($"Неподдерживаемый пакет: State = {ws.State}, WebSocketMessageType = {wsResult.MessageType}, Count = {wsResult.Count}, EndOfMessage = {wsResult.EndOfMessage}");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Самое сложное к пониманию здесь - метод `ReceiveAsync`, он принимает сообщения и выводит их к консоль, а так же отвечает за штатное закрытие соединения с сервером, которое может быть инициировано как со стороны клиента, так и со стороны сервера. И вот в этом месте вам на базе `TcpClient` пришлось бы изрядно попотеть, чтобы научиться управлять подключениями к серверу.

### Сервер

А вот с сервером все намного веселее, он состоит из целых 6 классов, правда большинство из них выглядит весьма просто. Начнем с потокобезопасной коллекции.

Ни одна из существующих коллекций `System.Collections.Concurrent` мне не подошла, потому что мне нужны были 3 операции: `Add(T)` добавить элемент, `Remove(T)` удалить элемент и `IEnumerable<T>` получить все элементы. Максимум 2 из 3. Поэтому привет первый велосипед.

**ConcurrentList.cs**

```cs
class ConcurrentList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _list;
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock;

    public ConcurrentList()
    {
        _list = new List<T>();
        _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _lock.EnterWriteLock();
        _list.Add(item);
        _lock.ExitWriteLock();
    }

    public void Remove(T item)
    {
        _lock.EnterWriteLock();
        _list.Remove(item);
        _lock.ExitWriteLock();
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> Enumerate()
    {
        _lock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            foreach (T item in _list)
                yield return item;
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() 
        => Enumerate().GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() 
        => Enumerate().GetEnumerator();
}
```

Очень хороший пример использования `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, запомните его. Reader-Writer Lock - это шаблон проектирования для максимально быстрого доступа к данным из нескольких потоков. Суть в том, что данные можно безопасно читать, пока никто не пишет, а вот писать безопасно может только один поток и при этом никто не может читать, все ждут.

Разогрев пройден, теперь во-взрослому

**ChatServer.cs**

```cs
class ChatServer
{
    private readonly HttpListener _listener;
    private readonly ConnectionManager _manager;

    public ChatServer(int port)
    {
        _listener = new HttpListener();
        _listener.Prefixes.Add($"http://localhost:{port}/ws/");
        _listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
        _manager = new ConnectionManager();
    }

    public async Task ListenAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            _listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Сервер стартовал на " + _listener.Prefixes.First());
            while (true)
            {
                HttpListenerContext context = await _listener.GetContextAsync();
                if (context.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("HTTP Подключение: " + context.Request.RemoteEndPoint + " > " + context.Request.LocalEndPoint);
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
                    await _manager.RunConnectionAsync(context);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed;
                    context.Response.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (HttpListenerException ex)
        {
            if (ex.ErrorCode == 995)
                Console.WriteLine("Сервер остановлен.");
            else
                throw ex;
        }
    }

    public async Task StopAsync()
    {
        if (_listener.IsListening)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Отключаю подключенных клиентов...");
            await _manager.CloseAllAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Клиенты отключены.");
            _listener.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Реализация этого класса практически идентична тому, что я раньше писал для `TcpListener`.

Управлять этим классом достаточно легко:

**Program.cs**

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChatServer server = new ChatServer(8080); // порт 8080
        Task servertask = server.ListenAsync();
        while (true)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input == "stop")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Остановка сервера...");
                await server.StopAsync();
                break;
            }
        }
        await servertask;
        Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу для выхода...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Немного асинхронности и готово.

Если вернуться к `ChatServer`, можно обнаружить, что он использует некий `ConnectionManager`. Это не стандартный класс, и задача его запускать новые вебсокеты на новых подключениях, ну и уметь их все отключить.

**ConnectionManager.cs**

```cs
class ConnectionManager
{
    private readonly ConcurrentList<Task> _tasks;
    private readonly Room _room;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public ConnectionManager()
    {
        _tasks = new ConcurrentList<Task>();
        _room = new Room("Прихожая");
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public async Task RunConnectionAsync(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        WebSocketConnection connection = new WebSocketConnection(context);
        Task task = RunAsync(connection, _cts.Token);
        _tasks.Add(task);
        _ = task.ContinueWith(_ => _tasks.Remove(task));
        await _room.EnterAsync(connection);
    }

    private async Task RunAsync(WebSocketConnection connection, CancellationToken token)
    {
        await connection.Run(token);
        _room.Leave(connection);
    }

    public async Task CloseAllAsync()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        await Task.WhenAll(_tasks.ToArray());
        _cts.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Смысл в том, что новое подключени попадает в список, а как только оно закрывается - сразу из этого списка удалится. А список нужен только для того чтобы иметь возможность штатно закрыть все подключения, когда сервер останавливается.

В `ConnectionManager` можно уже найти 2 оставишихся класса: `Room` и `WebSocketConnection`. По сути этот класс комбинирует 2 роли: обслуживает подключения и добавляет эти подключения в чат-команту, кстати вот комната.

**Room.cs**

```cs
class Room
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly ConcurrentList<WebSocketConnection> _connections;
    private readonly ConcurrentList<Task> _readers;

    public Room(string name)
    {
        _connections = new ConcurrentList<WebSocketConnection>();
        _readers = new ConcurrentList<Task>();
        _name = name;
    }

    public async Task EnterAsync(WebSocketConnection connection)
    {
        await BroadcastMessageAsync($"{connection.User} вошел в чат {_name}");
        _connections.Add(connection);
        await connection.Writer.WriteAsync($"{connection.User}, добро пожаловать в чат {_name}");
        Task task = RunReaderAsync(connection);
        _readers.Add(task);
        _ = task.ContinueWith(_ => _readers.Remove(task));
    }

    private async Task RunReaderAsync(WebSocketConnection connection)
    {
        await foreach (string message in connection.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
        {
            string text = $"{connection.User}: {message}";
            await BroadcastMessageAsync(text);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }

    private async Task BroadcastMessageAsync(string message)
    {
        foreach (WebSocketConnection connection in _connections)
        {
            await connection.Writer.WriteAsync(message);
        }
    }

    public void Leave(WebSocketConnection connection)
    {
        _connections.Remove(connection);
    }
}
```

Задача комнаты получать сообщения из всех зарегистрированных подключений и отправлять эти сообщения всем подключенным к комнате вебсокетам.

Ну и напоследок, самая важная часть сервера - та часть, которая непосредственно общается с клиентом.

**WebSocketConnection.cs**

```cs
class WebSocketConnection
{
    private readonly HttpListenerContext _context;
    private readonly Channel<string> _sendChannel;
    private readonly Channel<string> _receiveChannel;
    private HttpListenerBasicIdentity _identity;

    public string User => HttpUtility.UrlDecode(_identity.Name);
    public ChannelWriter<string> Writer => _sendChannel.Writer;
    public ChannelReader<string> Reader => _receiveChannel.Reader;

    public WebSocketConnection(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _sendChannel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
        _receiveChannel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
    }

    public async Task Run(CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            using CancellationTokenRegistration registration = token.Register(() => CompleteChannels());
            WebSocketContext wsContext = await _context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null);
            _identity = (HttpListenerBasicIdentity)wsContext.User.Identity;
            Console.WriteLine($"WebSocket подключение: {_context.Request.RemoteEndPoint}");
            WebSocket ws = wsContext.WebSocket;
            Task readerTask = ReceiveAsync(ws);
            await foreach (string message in _sendChannel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
            {
                await ws.SendAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            if (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Закрываю WebSocket: {_context.Request.RemoteEndPoint}");
                await ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.EndpointUnavailable, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            await readerTask;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)  { }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
            _context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }
        _context.Response.Close();
        Console.WriteLine($"Соединение закрыто: {_context.Request.RemoteEndPoint}");
            
    }

    private void CompleteChannels()
    {
        _receiveChannel.Writer.Complete();
        _sendChannel.Writer.Complete();
    }

    private async Task ReceiveAsync(WebSocket ws)
    {
        Memory<byte> buffer = new byte[1024];
        List<byte> data = new List<byte>();
        while (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            ValueWebSocketReceiveResult wsResult = await ws.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
            switch (wsResult.MessageType)
            {
                case WebSocketMessageType.Close when ws.State == WebSocketState.CloseReceived:
                    await ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
                    Console.WriteLine($"WebSocket закрыт клиентом: {_context.Request.RemoteEndPoint}");
                    CompleteChannels();
                    break;
                case WebSocketMessageType.Close:
                    Console.WriteLine($"WebSocket закрыт сервером: {_context.Request.RemoteEndPoint}");
                    break;
                case WebSocketMessageType.Text:
                    data.AddRange(buffer[..wsResult.Count].ToArray());
                    if (wsResult.EndOfMessage)
                    {
                        await _receiveChannel.Writer.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data.ToArray()));
                        data.Clear();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine($"Неподдерживаемый пакет от {_context.Request.RemoteEndPoint}: State = {ws.State}, WebSocketMessageType = {wsResult.MessageType}, Count = {wsResult.Count}, EndOfMessage = {wsResult.EndOfMessage}");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Этот класс немного похож на код клиента, который опубликован в самом начале этого ответа. Основная разница в том, что там мы читали из консоли и пписали в консоль, а здесь - читаем из `Channel` и пишем в другой `Channel`. Канал `Channel` - это некий туннель для данных с буфером. Закидываем туда строку и она куда-то улетела, а куда - в `Room`. То же самое в обратном направлении.

Каналы являются реализацией популярного шаблона проектирования для многопоточного программирования Producer/Consumer и являются относительно новшевством в .NET, появились они и доступны только начиная с версии **.NET Core 3.1**. Подробнее о каналах можно почитать [здесь](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/).

### Тестирование

Сценарий

1. Запускаем сервер
2. Запускаем Васю
3. Запускаем Петю
4. Что-то пишем с обоих клиентов
5. Закрываем Петю написав `exit` в консоль
6. Останавливаем сервер написав `stop` в консоль
7. Закрывем Васю, он уже отключен, ничего писать не надо

Сервер

```
Сервер стартовал на http://localhost:8080/ws/
HTTP Подключение: 127.0.0.1:55824 > 127.0.0.1:8080
WebSocket подключение: 127.0.0.1:55824
HTTP Подключение: 127.0.0.1:55828 > 127.0.0.1:8080
WebSocket подключение: 127.0.0.1:55828
Вася: всем привет от Васи
Петя: и тебе привет!
WebSocket закрыт клиентом: 127.0.0.1:55828
Соединение закрыто: 127.0.0.1:55828
stop
Остановка сервера...
Отключаю подключенных клиентов...
Закрываю WebSocket: 127.0.0.1:55824
WebSocket закрыт сервером: 127.0.0.1:55824
Соединение закрыто: 127.0.0.1:55824
Клиенты отключены.
Сервер остановлен.
Нажмите любую клавишу для выхода...
```

Клиент Вася

```
Введите имя: Вася
Соединение установлено
Вася, добро пожаловать в чат Прихожая
Петя вошел в чат Прихожая
всем привет от Васи
Вася: всем привет от Васи
Петя: и тебе привет!
WebSocket закрыт сервером, нажмите Enter для выхода...

Соединение закрыто
```

Клиент Петя

```
Введите имя: Петя
Соединение установлено
Петя, добро пожаловать в чат Прихожая
Вася: всем привет от Васи
и тебе привет!
Петя: и тебе привет!
exit
WebSocket закрыт клиентом
Соединение закрыто
```

Забыл сказать, логин пользователя передается через встроенную фишку протокола HTTP - Basic Authentication. То есть мне не надо в каждом сообщении от Васи писать его имя, сервер и так его уже при подключении прочитал из HTTP заголовков и запомнил. Сюда же проще простого прикрутить пароли для входа.

Решение получилось расширяемое, можно добавить пароли, комнаты, всякие красивые приветствия и прощания от сервера, приватные сообщения добавить команды для комнаты, показывать список присутствующих. В общем, почти готовый настоящий чат. Еще один хороший бонус этого решеия - `WebSocket`. Вам не составит труда написать клиент для чата под браузер, и кстати отдать его прямо с этого же сервера как веб-страницу.

---

Архив с решением на Яндекс.Диске - https://disk.yandex.ru/d/YJL0GyS2RT1hlQ

Comment: Спасибо за помощь и за столь обширное, понятное решение!

Comment: @Yoda на самом деле есть всякие библиотеки в NuGet пакетах, типа `WebSocketSharp` (есть и другие), которые могут сделать код работы с сетью проще. Но я решил показать именно на базе встроенных в .NET средств. А сервер профессиональный разработчик бы вообще делал на базе ASP.NET Core. Со временем вы до всех этих штук тоже доберетесь. Рад, что у вас все получилось.

Comment: До всего еще надо добраться и во многом разобраться. С такой помощью это будет быстрее)