# Как деактивировать одного из клиентов?

Tags: c#, сокет, клиент-сервер

```
    Это сервер здесь я в момент когда присваиваю имя, ещё вызываю метод 
    BlockBoard если Server.Clients.Count != 0 ну в общем если это первый 
    клиент, то пусть он будет белым

 private void HandleComand(string data)
{
    if (data.Contains("#setname"))
    {

        BlockBoard();
        _userName = data.Split('&')[1];
        UpdateChat();
        return;
    }
    if (data.Contains("#newmsg"))
    {
        string message = data.Split('&')[1];
        ChatController.AddMessage(_userName, message);
        return;
    }
    if (data.Contains("#changePos"))
    {
        string message = data.Split('&')[1];
        ChatController.ChangePosition(_userName, data.ToString());
        return;
    }

}

public void BlockBoard()
{
    string data = "";
    if (Server.Clients.Count == 0)
    {
        data = "#white";
    }
    else
    {
        data = "#black";
    }
    
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    int bytesSent = _handler.Send(buffer);
}
```

Затем в клиенте я получаю этот white, а что дальше с ним делать?

```
while (_serverSocket.Connected)
{

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8196];
    int bytesRec = _serverSocket.Receive(buffer);
    string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRec);

    if (data.Contains("#white"))
    {
        this.isWhitePlayer = true;
    }
    else if (data.Contains("#black"))
    {
        this.isWhitePlayer = false;
    }
    if (data.Contains("#updatechat"))
    {
        UpdateChat(data);
        continue;
    }
    if (data.Contains("#Updateboard"))
    {
        UpdateBoardd(data);
        continue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Обязательно было заморачиваться на сокетах? Такая куча кода. Есть же `TcpListener`+`TcpClient`, ну или даже лучше `HttpListener`+`WebSocket`. Но отдать должное, несмотря на проблемы с дизайном кода и полное отсутствие асинхронности, выглядит отлично.

Comment: Вот кстати [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567) работы в вебсокетами. Главная фишка вебсокета в том, что он полностью совместим с браузером (легко написать клиент для браузера на JavaScript). Второе, что бы я вам посоветовал - данные пакетов хранить в объектах для данных, сериализовать их в JSON, чтобы передавать по сети как текст. Если применить хотя-бы это к вашему решению, код клиента похудеет раза в 2, а то и больше. А сервер сможет обслуживать не 2 клиента, любое количество, одновременно.

Comment: Привет, спасибо за совет, но я сейчас уже не успею переделать, а ты по сокетам не сможешь помочь? Как обратиться к конктреному клиенту, мне нужно одного заблокировать, а другой чтобы работал, я получаю от сервера флаг isWhite = true; но что дальше, как мне в клиенте, имея этот флаг указать, что если флаг isWhite = true; то сейчас деактивируется 2-ая форма, то есть фторой клиент, а если isWhite = false; то деактивиируется 1-ый клиент. Очень нужно, если соображаешь в этом подскажи будь добр

Comment: Я отменил изменения в вопросе, которые вы сейчас внесли, потому что ответ уже в таком случае не относится к вашему вопросу. Если у вас появился новый вопрос, его надо задать отдельно, а не редактировать уже отвеченный. Вы можете из нового вопроса сослаться на ответ из текущего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слишком много лишнего кода в вопросе.

Собственно, тебе нужно понять кто именно ходит первым (кто за белых).

Допустим ты создаешь флаг "isWhitePlayer". А дальше все просто - если сейчас ход белых - проверяешь флаг на True - клиент может ходить.

Если сейчас ход черных - проверяешь флаг на False - клиент может ходить.

А по какой логике ты присвоишь тому или иному игроку цвет выбирать тебе.

---

на стороне клиента внутри Listener добавь:

```
if (data.Contains("#white"))
{
    this.isWhitePlayer = true;
    continue;
}
else if (data.Contains("#black"))
{
    this.isWhitePlayer = false;
    continue;
}
```

---

на стороне сервера - отправляй эти самые "#black" и "#white" на самом начале игры каждому из клиентов

---

Если на стороне клиента не наш ход(проверяя this.isWhitePlayer и теперешний ход должны делать черные или белые ) - не делаем SendPosition.

Comment: а я это должен делать на сервере или уже в клиенте?

Comment: флаг - на клиенте достаточно. Не вижу особого смысла проверки на сервере - слишком много телодвижений с отменой команды.

Comment: А как мне на стороне клиента понять, как это клиент, ведь клиенты хранятся в сервере, там есть List Clients там я их создаю и присваиваю одного поле colorName = white, другому black. А в клиенте я не понимаю как обратиться к конкретному клиенту, в общем запутался конкретно

Comment: так при присваивании цвета клиенту на стороне сервера - вышли обоим клиентам по сигналу какой из них какой. Ну и тогда делай запись в флаг.

Comment: А как примерно это будет выглядеть можешь написать?

Comment: public Client(Socket socket, int countClients)
        {
            if (countClients == 0)
            {
                _colorName = "White";
                //
            }
            else
            {
                _colorName = "Black";
            }
            _id = countClients;
            //countClients++;
            _handler = socket;
            _userThread = new Thread(Listener);
            _userThread.IsBackground = true;
            _userThread.Start();
        }

Comment: Обновил ответ. Вообще с сокетами не работал поэтому код чисто пальцем в небо, я ориентировался на твой код при написании этого. Гарантии идеальности подхода не даю - уверен можно и красивее написать.

Comment: ладно, спасибо, сейчас чай допью и буду дальше воевать, вроде примерно понял направление)

Comment: Привет, я сделал как ты говоришь и на стороне клиента от сервера получаю white or black, соответственно флаг isWhitePlayer переводится в тру или фолс, но что мне это даёт? я же по прежнему обращаюсь к обеим формам, как мне кажется. если я выполню метод deactivateButtons, то кнопки везде отключатся, а мне нужно, чтобы кнопки отлючались только на одном клиенте, как мне обратиться к конкретному клиенту не подскажешь?

Comment: смотри, ты же знаешь когда есть ход черных а когда белых, правильно? Ну вот это тебе дает возможность проверять "если это ход черных и если это черный игрок - значит можно давать клиенту право ходить" и "если это ход белых и если это белый игрок - значит можно давать клиенту право ходить" -- иначе - клиент не может ходить и просто ждет своей очереди.

Comment: Не уверен, что я это знаю, я просто с сервера получаю например "#white" и тогда я оказываюсь в клиенте и там должен что-то делать, а что там делать не знаю, потому что если я деактивирую кнопки, то они деактивируются в обоих клиентах, а мне нужно, чтобы они деактивировались только в одном

Comment: я изменил вопрос, добавил туда новый код, посмотри, может знаешь. что у меня тут не так