# Как сделать так, чтобы клиент слушал постоянно сервер?

Tags: c#, сокет, tcp, chat

Я имею консольный чат на сокетах, вот его код:

```
    using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace SocketTcpServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static int port = 8005; // порт для приема входящих запросов


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // получаем адреса для запуска сокета
            IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);


            Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                // связываем сокет с локальной точкой, по которой будем принимать данные
                listenSocket.Bind(ipPoint);

                // начинаем прослушивание
                listenSocket.Listen(10);

                Console.WriteLine("Сервер запущен. Ожидание подключений...");

                while (true)
                {

                    Socket handler = listenSocket.Accept();
                    // получаем сообщение
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        int bytes = 0; // количество полученных байтов
                        byte[] data = new byte[256]; // буфер для получаемых данных

                        do
                        {
                            bytes = handler.Receive(data);
                            builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                        }
                        while (handler.Available > 0);

                        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ": " + builder.ToString());

                        // отправляем ответ
                        string message = "ваше сообщение доставлено";
                        data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                        handler.Send(data);
                        
                        // закрываем сокет
                        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        handler.Close();
                    });
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Это был Сервер.

Сейчас покажу код клиента:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SocketTcpClient
{
    class Program
    {
        // адрес и порт сервера, к которому будем подключаться
        static int port = 8005; // порт сервера
        static string address = "127.0.0.1"; // адрес сервера
        static string message = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
        
            while (message != "EndProgram")
            {
                try
                {
                    IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(address), port);

                    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                    // подключаемся к удаленному хосту
                    socket.Connect(ipPoint);
                    Console.Write("Введите сообщение:");
                    message = Console.ReadLine();
                    byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                    socket.Send(data);

                    // получаем ответ
                    data = new byte[256]; // буфер для ответа
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    int bytes = 0; // количество полученных байт

                    do
                    {
                        bytes = socket.Receive(data, data.Length, 0);
                        builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                    }
                    while (socket.Available > 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("ответ сервера: " + builder.ToString());

                    // закрываем сокет
                    // socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    // socket.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Для завершения нажмите любую кнопку.");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Как я могу сделать так, чтобы мой клиент слушал сервер постоянно и получал от него сообщения? Наподобие дискорда или чата в стиме, где люди отправляют сообщения и сервер их пересылает пользователям?

Comment: Есть [консольный чат на вебсокетах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567) - сойдет?

Comment: А так, вам клиент надо распилить на 2 потока, один должен принимать данные из сокета и выбрасывать их в консоль, второй должен читать консоль и писать прочитанное в сокет, 2 потока, в каждом бесконечный цикл.

Comment: @aepot , Простите, я не могу понять, что означает "читать консоль и писать прочитанное в сокет"?

Comment: `ReadLine` и `socket.Send`

Comment: Ну socket.Write же нету? Я походу что-то не так понял

Comment: Простите, `socket.Send`, опечатался. И кстати, вы же вроде знакомы с асинхронным программированием. Почему вы опять пишете синхронный код для сети?

Comment: @aepot Разве? Task.Factory.StartNew же позволяет обрабатывать много запросов сразу, а не ждать каждый по отдельности.

Comment: @aepot , ну, т.е позволяет не ждать одному клиенту пока другой отправит сообщение.

Comment: То есть вы пока не различаете асинхронность и многопоточность. А надо бы уже различать. Но я вообще не про сервер, а про клиент выше писал.

Comment: @aepot А зачем в данном случае асинхронность? У меня сервер кроме обработки сообщений еще ничего дополнительно не надо делать.

Comment: @aepot , А, вы имели в виду клиент? А зачем ему вообще асинхронность? Он просто отправляет сообщение.

Comment: @aepot , Слушайте, а не можете выше сказанное скинуть кодом, пожалуйста? А то не понимаю, как это впихнуть надо.

Comment: Чтобы понять, зачем нужна асинхронность при работе с сетью, нужно понять - что такое асинхронность. Но забудьте вы уже про нее, я вам сказал `клиент надо распилить на 2 потока, один должен принимать данные из сокета и выбрасывать их в консоль, второй должен читать консоль и писать прочитанное в сокет, 2 потока, в каждом бесконечный цикл` - всё, больше ничего не надо. `не понимаю, как это впихнуть надо` - это нормально, надо чуть-чуть подумать. Потоки запускать умеете, циклы писать тоже.

Comment: @aepot Понял, попробую. Спасибо, что указали, куда тут двигаться.

Comment: @aepot Вы хоть тут меня на форуме терпите)

Comment: Чтож все SO форумом пытаются назвать, ну не так это, не так! Почитайте хотяб [тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour), увидите там `мы создаём свободную библиотеку подробных ответов на любой прикладной вопрос` ... `Этот сайт посвящён исключительно получению ответов. Это не форум для дискуссий.`. Хватит этот сайт воспринимать форумом, это не так! Тут другие правила, другие требования и все другое. Как минимум, люди сюда должны приходить не по каждому пустяку, а имея существенный вопрос/ответ, который будет полезен не только задающему/отвечающему, но и будущим читателям.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Поэтому я и задал такой вопрос.

Comment: @CsHarpUser ваш вопрос является дубликатом того, что я прилинковал в первом комментарии, используйте предложенный мной ответ, он решил проблему автора из прошлого вопроса.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [TcpChat (Console)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247412/tcpchat-console)