# Обработка исключения Socket.SendTo

Tags: c#, udp

Есть сервер на UDP, к нему подключаются пользователи и сервер их добавляет в `List<IPEndPoint> clients`.
При рассылке сообщений он проходится по списку пользователей, но если этот пользователь отключился и не сказал об этом серверу, то сервер выдает исключение и завершает работу.

Код рассылки сообщений:

```
private static void BroadcastMessage(string message, string ip)
{
    byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);

    for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
        if (clients[i].Address.ToString() != ip) 
            listeningSocket.SendTo(data, clients[i]);
}
```

Как правильно это обработать, чтобы сервер не завершал работу? Или может есть способ, который проверял бы перед отправкой можно ли отправить сообщение этому пользователю?

P.S.
Пример кода брал отсюда: [Сервер](https://gist.github.com/vasyukovff/974ad6bdede3603bb0ac07ee4ca03dbd)/[Клиент](https://gist.github.com/vasyukovff/83fd162cd2f8798eef16d688a3ac70ee) (Автор: [vasyukovff](https://gist.github.com/vasyukovff))

---

Пробовал сделать так:

```
private static void BroadcastMessage(string message, string ip)
{
    byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);

    for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
        if (clients[i].Address.ToString() != ip) 
        {
            try
            {
                listeningSocket.SendTo(data, clients[i]);
            }
            catch
            {
                clients.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
}
```

Но все так же получаю исключение и завершение работы сервера.

Comment: `try-catch` [Исключения и обработка исключений](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/)

Comment: @aepot Пробовал `listeningSocket.SendTo(data, clients[i]);` добавлять в `try-catch`, все так же.

Comment: [Пример чата на базе WebSocket](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567)

Comment: Покажите, как именно вы пытались это сделать.

Comment: @aepot Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: в какой строчке исключение при наличии `try-catch` и какое в нем сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: `но если этот пользователь отключился и не сказал об этом серверу` - UDP протокол не имеет понятия о том, что такое установленное соединение, там вообще невозможно установить соединение. Можно только отправлять сообщения (UDP Datagram) и слушать порт, на который эти сообщения приходит. Так что возможно происходит не совсем то, о чём вы думаете.

Comment: @aepot _Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее соединение. ...\Server.exe <процесс 21256> завершил работу с кодом 0._ Это все, никакую строку кода не передает.

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) Console.WriteLine($"{clients[i].Address.ToString()}: {ex.Message}");` - выводите нормальное сообщение об ошибке. Но оно скорее всего падает вообще не здесь. Запустите сервер из студии в режиме отладки, студия покажет, где сломалось.

Comment: @aepot Студия ничего не показывает, лишь добавляет что можно "автоматически закрывать консоль, при остановке отладки".

Comment: @aepot Добавление `catch (Exception ex) Console.WriteLine($"{clients[i].Address.ToString()}: {ex.Message}");` так же ничего не изменило, ошибка все та же. Суть ошибки я как бы понимаю, я пытаюсь отправить сообщение пользователю которого больше нет в списке.

Comment: `Студия ничего не показывает` быть такого не может. Если вы запустили приложение в режиме отладки, то студитя остановит приложение ровно в той строчке, где возникло исключение.

Comment: @aepot Я конечно могу отправлять серверу сообщение типо "disconnect" и чтобы он в итоге удалил из списка этого пользователя, но всякое может случиться и сообщение не отправится.

Comment: @aepot Режим отладки запускается, но разницы никакой.

Comment: Если у вас студия при возникновении исключения не останавливается на строке, где оно возникло, значит код выполняется не в режиме отладки. И если вам не помогает `try-catch`, где вы его добавили, значит исключение возникает в другом месте.

Comment: @aepot Отладка -> Начать отладку (F5). Если я ставлю точки останова, то он останавливает. Не знаю как еще доказать.

Comment: проект -> свойства -> сборка -> активный(отладка) -> убрать галку "оптимизировать код" и пересобрать проект.

Comment: @aepot Галочка не стоит.

Comment: Научитесь отлаживать код, а не просто копировать готовое и запускать его. Вот что у вас в сервере написано? Я допустим вижу там несколько `try/catch`, которые выводят просто текст ошибки, но не где произошла, из-за чего и так далее. Поставьте точки остановки в каждом блоке `catch` и смотрите `StackTrace`, который скажет на какой строке у вас упало приложение, а лучше, уберите вовсе все `catch`, ибо оборачивать всю программу, глупо. Когда найдете место, где падает приложение, смотрите уже из-за чего это происходит и исправляйте.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Так я знаю где падает приложение, я хочу сделать чтобы оно не падало. Приложение пытается отправить сообщение пользователю, который перестал слушать адрес сервера и поэтому получает исключение. Я же не спрашиваю где падает приложение.

Comment: @Алексей Если вы обернули этот участок кода в `try/catch` и это не дало какого либо результата, то вы точно уверены, что оно падает именно там? Я вот сомневаюсь...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Оно падает на методе `Listen()`, но суть не в этом. Мне нужно понять как удалить пользователя из списка, вместо этого исключения.

Comment: @Алексей Суть как раз в этом, вам надо сначала определить конкретно, где приложение падает и делать проверку (если возможно), либо оборачивать в `try/catch`. Если приведенный вами код не работает, то повторюсь, ошибка значит не в том месте! Также замечу, что делать `clients.RemoveAt(i);` в момент, когда вы пробегаетесь по этому же циклу, плохо, хотяб делайте цикл с конца.

Comment: Да, кстати, или цикл с конца или так `clients.RemoveAt(i--)`