# C# tcp listener завис

Tags: c#, .net, http

```
        server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);

        string urladdress = "http://" + ipAddress.ToString() + ":" + port + "/";
        Console.WriteLine(urladdress);
        server.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ожидание подключений... ");

            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Подключен клиент. Выполнение запроса...");

            HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(client.ReadAll()); //На этой строчке программа останавливается
            httpRequest.Parse();
            //...
        }
```

Суть в чем, я создаю http сервер. Клиент заходит на сервер, отправляет данные, сервер их получает, генерирует ответ и собственно отправляет. Программа останавливается на получении данных от клиента.

Вот метод ReadAll, на котором останавливается программа:

```
public static string ReadAll(this TcpClient client)
        {
            using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream()))
            {
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }    
        }
```

Я так понял, что клиент не отправляет данные, но почему?

Comment: Чтобы сервер получил данные, нужен клиент, который подключится к серверу по TCP. Вы можете создать другую консольную программу и там создать `new TcpClient()`, передав ему нужный ip-адрес и номер порта. Для TCP-протокола не используйте `ReadToEnd`, работайте с `NetworkStream` и его методом `Read`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko я делаю веб-фрейворк, зачем мне делать свой клиент? А на счет ReadToEnd для Tcp по подробнее. Почему нельзя использовать?

Comment: Я несколько раз подумал, и решил закрыть этот вопрос, потому что здесь долго было бы рассказывать как правильно прочитать HTTP пакет, который не распарсив заголовки, невозможно прочитать правильно. То есть сначала построчно парсим заголовки как текст, оттуда достаем длину контента, потом вычитываем контент как двоичные данные, и если `Content-Type` текстовый, то тогда преобразуем в текст. Ответ на этот вопрос был бы очень похож на прилинкованный ответ. В любом случае, код, который в прилинкованном ответе расскажет вам больше, чем я в комментариях.

Comment: Если хотите использовать реализацию HTTP из дотнета, а не пилить свой велосипед, то обязательно поизучайте, как работает `HttpListener`. Он сам вам распарсит пакет и выдаст готовые данные. Как использовать `HttpListener`, можно увидеть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567).

Comment: `Я так понял, что клиент не отправляет данные, но почему?` отвечаю на ваш вопрос прямо: клиент отправляет данные, но после отправки не закрывает соединение, в принятых данных вы можете увидеть HTTP заголовок `Connection: keep-alive`, а `StreamReader` будет висеть на чтении из потока до тех пор, пока соединение не будет закрыто. Как это вылечить - я выше написал. Вместо `sr.ReadToEnd()` попробуйте `while (!sr.EndOfStream) Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine())` и вы увидите полученные данные, но проблемы с зависаловом это не решит.

Comment: @aepot я сначала использовал HttpListener, а потом перешел на TcpListener, потому что мне не хватало гибкости, а распарсить http запрос может любой первоклассник

Comment: @Lofectr ну я бы так не топил за первоклассника. Мне тоже казалось, что это как 2 пальца, пока не начал читать [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616).

Comment: @aepot мне пока что нужны лишь пару заголовков, остальное пока что для меня лишнее

Comment: Ну берите тогда готовый движок из прилинкованного ответа, выкидывайте из него лишнее, и готово. Там решение, которое может кучу клиентов одновременно обслуживать к тому же, прям то что доктор прописал.