# Клиент-серверное приложение C# Android

Tags: c#, .net

Есть клиент-серверное приложение. Клиенты написаны под десктоп и Android(Xamarin), сервер служит для управления базой данных и рассылки сообщений клиентам о том, что какой-то клиент поменял запись в базе данных. Клиентов будет подключаться не более 10. Я сделал подключение через сокеты и обмен данными через сериализацию, но думаю, что данный способ не очень производительный и вообще не очень правильный.
Кто-то может поделить опытом и подсказать как лучше реализовать данный механизм?

PS Просьба не пинать, .NET это хобби и пишу для себя, просто интересно изучать новые технологии.

Comment: Ну передачу данных можно через [WebSocket сделать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567), сериализация в Json - вполне быстрая штука. Сервер то ASP.NET или самописный движок? Почему вы решили, что что-там непроизводительное?

Comment: Сервер самописный, так как приложение простое. Спасибо за статью.