# Как не ждать старую информацию с события

Tags: c#, события

У меня есть событие, оно постоянно, каждую секунду выдает информацию(websocket в общем).

У меня есть действие после получения сообщения(OnMessage), оно занимает время. И пока оно заняло это время, например 1 секунду, у меня отсает, и приходят старые сообщения. Т.е вместо свежей информации, он выдает старую, которая прошла уже.

Как мне это обойти? Чтобы он не делал действие со старой информацией, а делал действия с новой.

Выглядит это примерно так

```
Main:
socket.OnMessage += RecerveMessage;
```

Действие на message

```
private void RecerveMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs message)
{
    int numbertask = taskchek.taskarray.ToList().FindIndex(x => x.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);
            if(numbertask != -1)
            taskchek.taskarray[numbertask] = Task.Run(async() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Double.Parse(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(message.Data).p.Replace(".", ",")) + " : " + numbertask);
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("First Message " + message.Data);
                }
            });
   // Действие, занимающее 1 секунду
}
```

Пытался это решить массивом тасков, но пока таски запускаются, на это тоже тратится время, и информация приходит старая

Comment: Запускайте при вызове `RecerveMessage` новый асинхронный `Task`, который выполнит задачу, без блокировки всего остального. Дальше уже смотрите по ситуации, если надо останавливать старую "обработку", сделайте `CancellationToken`, который отдаст сигнал прерывания старым "тескам". Либо можно пойти в сторону каналов, в который будет добавляться новая информация, а по мере возможностям обрабатывать "на другой стороне" это все.

Comment: Не думал что async может что-то решить. Получается так должно быть ? `taskchek.taskarray[numbertask] = Task.Run(async() =>
            {`

Comment: Увы я использую библиотеку WebSocketSharp тут нет токенов

Comment: Я и пытаюсь на стороне делать, у меня действие парралельным получаться должно, чтобы не тормозить поток, а тут торомозило

Comment: [Есть вот такой пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567). Если кратко, то вам не хватает знаний о шаблоне проектирования Producer/Consumer, изучите реализации, в примере по ссылке она есть, на основе Channels. Данные должны идти неким потоком в обе стороны. То есть должен существовать некий буфер, который сохраняет порядок всего этого, и там ничего не теряется. WebSocketSharp использует другой шаблон - Publisher/Subscriber, который, очевидно, вам не очень подходит, и вы уже начали вокруг него городить костыли.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(5000);` никогда не делайте Sleep в асинхронных методах, а в идеале вообще никогда не делайте. Но если очень хочется, то для асинхронных методов есть `await Task.Delay(5000);`. Какая версия дотнета у вас?

Comment: @НикитаЧыпычкин `тут нет токенов` - токены, это механизм C#, а не библиотек. Ваша задача - понять, как работает как минимум, async/await. Вот к примеру у нас есть такой [код](https://pastebin.com/NPiJRndv), простые async/await. Как видите, там на каждое событие запускается новая задача, которая фоном доделываем свои дела, на выходе будет [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6k1K.png). Думаю заметили, получили - запустили - обработали.

Comment: @НикитаЧыпычкин Если нам надо чтоб выполнялась одна задача, то [чуть дополняем код](https://pastebin.com/SDuyNUrd) (внимание на токен). [Результат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KMd2.png) - как видите, если запускается новая задача (новое событие), то старые задачи завершают свою работу. То есть уже получается получили - запустили - обработали сколько смогли (пока не закрыли). Вот, собственно, вам и грубая реализация вашей задачи.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ как работает async/await я понимаю, но я даже не думал, что когда я даю шаблону таска, таск, оно может тормозить и выполнятся синхронно. но теперь знаю

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь