# Как использовать SIP в xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sip

Пишу мессенджер, в котором хочу реализовать Sip Сall

Но я нашел только этот код. И он подходит для приложений win. Как мне это сделать в xamarin.forms

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SIPSorcery.Media;
using SIPSorcery.SIP.App;
using SIPSorceryMedia.Windows;

namespace demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static string DESTINATION = "time@sipsorcery.com";

        static async Task Main()
        {
            var userAgent = new SIPUserAgent();
            var winAudioEndPoint = new WindowsAudioEndPoint(new AudioEncoder());
            var voipMediaSession = new VoIPMediaSession(winAudioEndPoint.ToMediaEndPoints());

            bool callResult = await userAgent.Call(DESTINATION, null, null, voipMediaSession);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/android.net.sip?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9 - оно?

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/csipsimple/

Comment: @aepot, я находил эту документацию , но мне нужен пример кода , что бы понять как ей пользоваться , а там его нет , там просто перебор методов , с небольшим описанием

Comment: Начните с того что почитайте как работает Session Initiation Protocol, изучите теорию. Потом начните разбирать документацию, разбив задачу на несколько частей: как создать соединение, как передавать по нему голос, как закрыть соединение. Под каждую из подзадач подойдет конкретный класс. Писать код можно самостоятельно, а не только копируя куски чужого. Если б я писал под Xamarin, у меня не составило бы труда решить эту задачу, вот например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567) я с нуля разобрался с WebSocket, просто читал спецификации. Это не просто, но уметь так делать надо.