# C# Wpf, реализация TcpListener через SignalR

Tags: c#

я делал сервер на основе TcpListener по протоколу Tcp,

по такому примеру

```
 string ip = "192.168.1.178";
 TcpListener serverSocket = new(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 51000);

 serverSocket.Start();
```

и соответственно ждал TcpClient , но можно ли как-то сдлеать эту реализацию через SignalR, тоесть я так понял есть протоколы, по которым он может работать, но как правильно запустить сервер на через SignalR

исправил и получилось

```
 private static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        //.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        //{
        //    services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(
        //                    context.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel"));
        //})
        //.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        //{
        //    webBuilder.UseStartup<StartUp>();
        //});
        .UseStartup<StartUp>()
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 100;
            options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 10 * 1024;
            options.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate =
                new MinDataRate(bytesPerSecond: 100, gracePeriod: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            options.Limits.MinResponseDataRate =
                new MinDataRate(bytesPerSecond: 100, gracePeriod: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.178"), 5100);
        })
        .Build();
```

Comment: SignalR может работать через WebSocket, [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567) я игрался с вебсокетами. Еще [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) почитайте.

Comment: @aepot попытался исправить, но что-то вроде не то

Comment: Текстовую информацию пожалуйста вставляйте текстом.

Comment: @aepot хорошо, извиняюсь, этот метод работает который я вставил картинкой, но я так понимаю сейчас все используют Host, вместо WebHost