# Как настроить сокет для переписки?

Tags: c#, клиент-сервер, сокеты

Всем привет! Хочу настроить сокет для переписки по localhost. Подскажите, обязательно ли в этом случае делать и клиента и сервер или можно настроить два клиента чтобы переписывались между собой?

Comment: если tcp - то сервер нужен. Если udp, то можно без сервера.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567