# Триггер ивента сервера на клиенте

Tags: c#

Создаю клиент-сервер приложение, в котором клиент делает запрос по http на сервер, а сервер его как-то обрабатывает (с помощью nancy). Для поддержания модульности, была создана библиотека по взаимодействию с сервером, где клиент обращается просто к статическим методам и получает ответ.

На сервере у меня реализована коллекция ObservableConcurrentDictionary, которая имеет внутри себя ивент по аналогии с ObservableCollection. Данная коллекция хранит внутри себя кэш базы данных. Из этой коллекции данные отправляются на клиент.

Итак, теперь сам вопрос: возможно ли в библиотеке по взаимодействию с сервером реализовать статический ивент, который сервер будет вызывать, а подписанные клиенты вызывать соответствующие методы у них.

Код прикладывать смысла не вижу, тк тут больше вопрос теоретический вопрос о том, в какую сторону копать.

Пример:

На сервере есть ObservableConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Order>, хранящая внутри себя заказы.

Есть ивент OrdersChanged, который вызывает при изменении коллекции, описанной выше.

При вызове ивента, срабатывают методы, подписанные на него

Upd:

Создана отдельная библиотека классов для того, чтобы перетянуть всю логику взаимодействия клиента с сервером на себя. Таким образом, на клиенте практически не нужно реализовывать какие-либо методы. Во ViewModel клиента нужно лишь вызвать статические методы той библиотеки

Comment: Вопрос про то, бывают ли статические ивенты? Да, `static` допишите. Если про пепедачу данных по инициативе сервера, то это либо поллинг, либо вебсокет. Клиент кто - браузер?

Comment: @aepot Клиент - консольное приложение, которое отвечает на http запросы. Я говорю про передачу данных по инициативе сервера. То есть, на сервере сработал ивент изменения свойства (OrdersChanged) и он своим клиентам говорит об этом

Comment: Проблема в том, что сервер не хранит в себе клиентов. Он только отвечает на http запросы (get, post и тд). Будет ли корректно добавить TcpListener и List<Client> на сервер? При срабатывании ивента будут отправляться всем клиентам сериализованные объекты (только как это на ивенты подвязать - вопрос)

Comment: Зависит от того, какой у вас интерес, если практический, то ASP.NET+SignalR, если спортивный, то https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567 для обратной связи по запросу сервера должно быть открытое соединение.

Comment: @aepot Благодарю. Можете оформить, как ответ, если есть желание. Поставлю галочку

Comment: Это скорее совет, а не ответ.