# Сервер закрыл соединение WebSocket, не завершив рукопожатие close

Tags: c#, парсер, websocket

У меня есть парсер, который получает обновления по Websocket и обрабатывает их в асинхронном методе. Проблема заключается в том что через 3-5 минут сервер разрывает соединение:

> One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.))

```
while (update)
try
{
    responce = GetResponce().Result;
    Update(responce);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Но если убрать метод Update, ошибка не появляется и соединение работает часами:

```
while (update)
try
{
    responce = GetResponce().Result;
    Console.WriteLine(responce);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Метод Update:

```
private async Task Update(string responce)
{
    try { 
        foreach (var tradingPair in TradingPairs)
            if ((tradingPair.TradingPairInfo.Symbol.ToLower() + "@depth").Equals(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CryptoBot.Binance.JsonModels.UpdateOrderBook>(responce).stream))
            {
                double[,] asks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CryptoBot.Binance.JsonModels.UpdateOrderBook>(responce).data.a;
                double[,] bids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CryptoBot.Binance.JsonModels.UpdateOrderBook>(responce).data.b;
                Int64 time = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CryptoBot.Binance.JsonModels.UpdateOrderBook>(responce).Time;
                for (int i = 0; i < asks.Length / 2; i++)
                    tradingPair.OrderBook.Update(asks[i, 0], asks[i, 1], TypeOrder.Asks, time);
                for (int i = 0; i < bids.Length / 2; i++)
                    tradingPair.OrderBook.Update(bids[i, 0], bids[i, 1], TypeOrder.Bids, time);
                tradingPair.OrderBook.read = true;
                break;
            }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

Метод GetResponce:

```
private async Task<string> GetResponce()
{
    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
    int size;
    ArraySegment<byte> buf;
    do
    {
        buf = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[buffer]);
        size = webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buf, CancellationToken.None).Result.Count;
        data.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf.ToArray(), 0, size));
    } while (size > buffer - 1);
    return data.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `GetResponce().Result` заменить на `await GetResponce()`.

Comment: `Update(responce)` заменить на `await Update(responce)`

Comment: Пройтись по всему коду и выкинуть все `.Result`. Везде поставить `await`.

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CryptoBot.Binance.JsonModels.UpdateOrderBook>(responce)` вызывается **4** раза! @#$%!

Comment: Alexander Petrov, спасибо за Ваш ответ, помогло !

Comment: Если в `TradingPairs` больше одного элемента, то `DeserializeObject` может вызываться даже больше чем 4 раза. В общем, стоит вызвать его один раз перед `foreach`-ем и сохранить результат в переменную

Comment: Что за библиотека вебсокета используется? Или родной? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567