# C# Ошибка подключения к серверу WebSocket

Tags: c#, сокет, websocket

При большом количестве подключений к серверу я получаю ошибку на стороне клиента Unable to connect to the remote server `Невозможно подключиться к удаленному серверу` При запуске количество ошибок всегда разное от 0 до 100 и т.п. При этом проект с сервером при нагрузке в 1000 подключений потребляет на 10мб больше озу, у клиентского приложения нагрузка полностью отсутствует. Подскажите как можно стабилизировать работу с сокетами.
Код сервера
`Program.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
});
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Programs");
builder.Services.AddSqlite<ContextProgram>(connectionString);
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions
{
    KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)
};
app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

`Код контролера`

```
 public class SocketController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("/ws")]
        public async Task Get()
        {
            if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                await Socket(webSocket);
            }
            else
            {
             //   HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
            }
        }
        private async Task Socket(WebSocket webSocket)
        {
            try
            {
                var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
                var receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(
                    new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

                while (!receiveResult.CloseStatus.HasValue)
                {
                    await webSocket.SendAsync(
                        new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, receiveResult.Count),
                        receiveResult.MessageType,
                        receiveResult.EndOfMessage,
                        CancellationToken.None);

                    receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(
                        new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
                    await Task.Delay(10);
                }
                await webSocket.CloseAsync(
                    receiveResult.CloseStatus.Value,
                    receiveResult.CloseStatusDescription,
                    CancellationToken.None);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                string message = ex.Message.ToString();
               // webSocket.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
```

`Код для проверки нагрузки на сервер или же просто подключение в многопотоке к серверу`

```
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;
CancellationTokenSource _cancelToken;
CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource = new();
Console.WriteLine("Start");

int thread = 1000;
_semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(thread);
_cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

var pool = new List<Task>(thread);

for (int i = 0; i < thread; i++)
{
    await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    int val = i;
    ClientWebSocket webSocketClient = new ClientWebSocket();
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = new();
    pool.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Socket(webSocketClient, cancellationToken, val);
        _semaphore.Release();
    }, _cancelToken.Token));
}

await Task.WhenAll(pool.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);
Console.WriteLine("Done");
Console.ReadKey();
async Task Socket(ClientWebSocket webSocketClient, CancellationToken cancellationToken, int i)
{
    string error = "";
    try
    {
        await webSocketClient.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://localhost:5000/ws"), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (webSocketClient.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            await Send(webSocketClient, i.ToString(), cancellationToken);
            await SocketNew(webSocketClient);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        error = ex.Message.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка подключения" + $" {error}");
        return;
    }
}
async Task Send(ClientWebSocket webSocketClient, string requestString, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var requestBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);
    var subscribeRequest = new ArraySegment<byte>(requestBytes);
    await webSocketClient.SendAsync(subscribeRequest, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
async Task SocketNew(WebSocket webSocket)
{
    try
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
        var receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
        while (!receiveResult.CloseStatus.HasValue)
        {
            string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, receiveResult.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("Ответ от сокета " + message + $" Поток: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            if (message != "")
            {
                await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Connection closed", CancellationToken.None);
                return;
            }
            receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при получение ответа");
    }
}
```

Ошибка
Ошибка подключения System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to the remote server
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение. (localhost:5001)
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketErr or error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.S ources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0( AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessag e request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellati onAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpReq uestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ClientWebSocketOptions options)
at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ClientWebSocketOptions options)
at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.ConnectAsyncCore(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<$>g__Socket|0>d.MoveNext() in D:\Project\Visul studio\Delete2\Delete2\Program.cs:line 43

Comment: На клиенте как-то странно реализована работа с вебсокетами, [вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567) работы с WS. `new SemaphoreSlim(thread);` - это вообще странность, это точно человек присал этот код? Смысл в семафоре, который грубо говоря выключен?

Comment: @aepot код писал человек, не гпт, про семафор знакомый когда то такую реализацию показывал, уже точно не скажу зачем он там нужен. Обновил вопрос в конце добавил текст ошибки. Ошибка происходит в момент подключения
`await webSocketClient.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://localhost:5000/ws"), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);`
Я посмотрел ваш пример, есть что взять на заметку) Но у вас пример с консольным приложением, на метанит видел также примеры где можно установить лимит подключений и т.п.

Comment: В моем случае у меня веб приложение и при большом количестве подключений сервер отклоняет подключения, в netstat смотрел какие порты используется, берутся каждый раз свободные, то есть проблема именно в веб приложение. А на стороне него в блоке try ошибок нет

Comment: @aepot так как у меня веб сервер и использую его из студии, для проверки может быть что какие то системные лимиты... было  бы подобное в реальном веб приложении. количество подключений было бы больше.

Comment: @aepot `new SemaphoreSlim(10);` Создание экземпляра объекта семафора с ограничением в 10 потоков, которые будут работать одновременно `await semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` Ожидание получения доступа к семафору для выполнения задачи. То есть этот код ограничивает запуск потоков  по 10 и ждет завершения какого либо потока, чтобы создать следующий поток
 `semaphore.Release();`  // Освобождение семафора после выполнения задачи

Comment: Не потоки он ограничивает а одновременно выполняющиеся операции, вы путаете асинхронность и многопоточность опять. Просто если у вас WaitAsync вызван 10 раз, а Release ни разу, то 11-й вызов WaitAsync поставит ваш код на паузу до тех пор, пока где-то не будет вызван Release чтобы сообщить семафору, что место освободилось. Потоки здесь совершенно не при чем.

Comment: @aepot  спасибо за подробное объяснение, теперь понял суть как семафор блокирует вызов  метода