# как правильно отправлять команды в сеть на C#

Tags: c#, сетевое-программирование, локальная-сеть

искал в гугле не нашел решений которые могли бы помочь, возможно плохо искал

нужен код для программы который будет отправлять в сеть команды.
и нужен код для другой проги которая принимает эти команды и выполняет действия при получении той или иной команды

про программу (клиент) которая должна отправлять команды:
есть программа в которой есть 39 кнопок и каждая должна отправлять определенную команду(это может быть слова, цифры и подобное) на определенный ip и порт

про программу (сервер) которая должна получает команды:
аналогичная прога только при нажатии кнопок команды выполняются на ноутбуке на котором она запущена(это есть и работает), только нужен код который получает команды от проги(клиент) и выполняет нужные действия

есть какие то советы, готовые решения

делается на С# для windows
в visual studio 2022
.NET 8.0
Windows Forms

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567

Comment: @aepot я такой же чат нашел тут https://metanit.com/sharp/net/4.4.php но никак не смог его приспособить, возможно плохо думал

Comment: Не такой же. Вот ещё примеры, изучайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+tcplistener

Comment: @aepot насколько я понял все эти варианты для консоли, а это автоматически не подходит

Comment: Неправильно вы поняли. Замените вывод в консоль на выполнение метода нужного и всё, больше не для консоли.

Comment: @aepot до меня прям видимо оочень не доходит что и где менять

Comment: Значит вы пока не готовы решать задачи такого уровня сложности.