# Отправка картинки TCP C#

Tags: c#, tcpclient

В общем есть код

```
static void Main()
    {
        TcpClient client = null;
        byte[] message = null;
        using (var req = new HttpRequest())
        {
            string image = string.Format("https://api.vk.com/captcha.php?sid={0}", "1657");
            Image captchaImage = Image.FromStream(req.Get(image).ToMemoryStream());
            System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            captchaImage.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            message = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        try
        {
            client = new TcpClient(address, port);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            while (true)
            {
                stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);

                message = new byte[1024];
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytes = stream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(message, 0, bytes));
                }
                while (stream.DataAvailable);

                string request = builder.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Сервер: {0}", request);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Close();
        }
    }
```

Не могу отправить картинку, пишет что `Не удается прочитать данные из транспортного соединения: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.`

Прием картинки

```
public TcpClient client;
    private static object locker = new object();
    public ClientObject(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        client = tcpClient;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        NetworkStream stream = null;
        try
        {
            stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            while (true)
            {
                int bytes = 0;
                byte[] mess = null;
                do
                {
                    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    mess = data;
                }
                while (stream.DataAvailable);

                Guid gd = new Guid();
                data = ImageProcessing(mess, gd.ToString());
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
            if (client != null)
                client.Close();
        }
    }
```

В чем моя ошибка? С сетями такого плана работаю в первый раз

Comment: Скажите честно, этот код вы писали, понимаете как он работает? [Пример TCP сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214630/373567)

Comment: @aepot большую часть писал не я, взял с метанита, да, как код работает понимаю, по крайней мере я так думаю

Comment: Ваша проблема внутри цикла `while (true)` на обоих концах. Ставьте точку останова и смотрите значения переменных выполняя код пошагово. Этот процесс называется ["отладка"](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @aepot (: спасибо

Comment: @aepot правильно ли код написал? Клиент должен отправить картинку и получить ответ от сервера и закрыть соединение 
`using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
{
 client.Connect(address, port);

 using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
 {
  stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length); 
  message = new byte[1024];
  int bytes = stream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
  Console.WriteLine("Сервер: {0}", Encoding.Unicode.GetString(message, 0, bytes));
 }
}`

Comment: если вы правильно написали код, значит он должен работать )

Comment: @aepot в принципе логично

Comment: Вопрос наводящий, как принимающий клиент узнает, какой длины ему летит файл? Как он идентифицирует конец сообщения? Никак, если вы ему явно не передадите длину передаваемых данных. Регламентирование формата передаваемых данных называется протокол передачи данных. Его-то вам и не хватает.

Comment: @aepot по сути, на стороне сервера кол-во считываемых байтов мы получаем из потока?
`byte[] Data = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
nt count = stream.Read(Data, 0, Data.Length);
Guid gd = new Guid();
byte[] data = ImageProcessing(Data, gd.ToString());
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);`

Comment: Нет, не так. Вы пытаетесь считать массив определенной длины, и получаете либо максимум, либо зависаете в ожидании, пока этот максимум не придет от клиента. Либо отвисаете, если клиент закрывает соединение. То есть да, косвенно вы можете прервать передачу закрыв соединение со стороны клиента, но я не уверен, что это вменяемый способ. Тогда вам нужно будет просто обработать возникшее исключение, которое вы поймали. По-хорошему вам нужно придумать протокол, например передать 1 байт как заголовок пакета (его и ждать на сервере), по этому байту определить тип пакета...

Comment: ...далее по типу пакета определить, что там дальше в заголовке пойдет, длина файла, кодировка текста, что-то еще, на что вам фантазии хватит, например для файла это может быть его длина и имя, потом, получили информацию о длине файла, вам нужно в один или несколько заходов в цикле прочитать этот файл, читая до тех пор, пока не достигните заранее известной длины. И только потом снова начать ожидание нового пакета. Это не так просто реализовать, как то что вы скопировали с обучающего сайта, но возможно. Самое сложное - это представить эту логику, описать себе протокол. Код написать проще потом.

Comment: @aepot спасибо за совет :) не думал что настолько все мудрено будет что бы отправить картинку, ибо когда я отправлял обычный текст, работало на ура

Comment: Вы отправляли текст и закрывали соединение, здесь вы можете так же поступить, только размер принимающего буфера у вас сколько байт? 1024, а размер файла? То есть вы можете создать `MemoryStream` и туда писать буферы пока не прилетит ноль, потом сделать `ms.ToArray()` и получите массив байт с вашими данными. Но вам придется переподключаться каждый раз к серверу после каждой передачи. Если вас это устраивает - можете так и сделать.

Comment: @aepot размер картинки максимум до 4kb

Comment: Я вам ссылку выше кинул на рабочий сервер, найдите в коде строчку `await _stream.CopyToAsync(ms, (int)length)` - это как раз и есть прием данных заранее известной длины, только там я из HTTP заголовка длину получаю, а вы можете по-своему сделать. У вас это может выглядеть как `using var ms = new MemoryStream(); stream.CopyTo(ms, length); byte[] file = ms.ToArray();` где length - заранее известная длина передаваемых данных. Так работают все протоколы, потому что переподключение к серверу - очень дорогая операция. Сервер дочитал данные до конца и тут же ждет следующий пакет.

Comment: @aepot все, разобрался и все работает, спасибо большое)