# Как правильно асинхронно читать SslStream по частям?

Tags: c#, сокет, асинхронность

Доброго времени суток!

На сервере в бесконечном цикле я читаю данные от клиента при помощи метода [`ReadAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.readasync?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Security_SslStream_ReadAsync_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) класса [`SslStream`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=net-5.0) приблизительно следующим образом:

```
// client_stream - экземпляр SslStream.
while (true) {
    // MemoryStream received_stream = ... // Поток принятых данных.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
    int bytes_read = 0;
    do {
        bytes_read = await client_stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, /* токен отмены */);
        // Добавляем данные в поток принятых данных received_stream.
    }
    while (bytes_read > 0);
    // Обрабатываем данные в потоке received_stream.
}
```

Что я пытаюсь сделать в этом алгоритме? Я по частям размером с длину `buffer` принимаю данные от клиента и записываю их в поток принятых данных, который по итогу будет заключать в себе обращение клиента к серверу, на которое клиент ожидает ответа. Вы могли заметить комментарий в конце "обрабатываем данные". А принятые данные то не обрабатываются **своевременно**.

Проблема заключается в том, что вызов `... = await client_stream.ReadAsync(...);`, как бы нелепо это ни звучало, блокирует выполнение потока. Первая итерация цикла `do .. while`: поток ждет данных, и это правильно. Допустим, он принял 2 байта. Выполнение продолжилось. Принятые байты добавлены в поток принятых данных. Количество принятых байт больше нуля. Переходим ко второй итерации цикла `do .. while`. Как Хатико ждем данных от клиента и получаем исключение. Что произошло? Клиент не дождался ответа на обращение и сбросил соединение с сервером. Браво! Алгоритм ничтожен.

В документации сказано, что `SslStream.ReadAsync` возвращает 0, когда больше нет данных для чтения, но на практике это приносит только головную боль: да, он возвращает 0 и не блокирует выполнение потока после вызова **`WriteAsync`**. Но если `WriteAsync` не вызывался, то он просто блокирует поток до получения данных от клиента. Лог переполнен, алгоритм не работает. Шикарно!

Я также не могу проверить количество доступных байт для чтения (в самом `SslStream`, а не сокете) для остановки цикла `do .. while`. Я не могу удостовериться в том, что я в конце потока `SslStream`. Это заводит меня в тупик и я уже долго не могу исправить алгоритм.

**Вопрос**: как мне исправить или реализовать алгоритм принятия (большого количества) данных от клиента по частям при том, что данные после получения должны быть обработаны как можно скорее (необходимо ответить клиенту или клиент разорвет соединение).

Comment: Чтобы прочитать порцию данных и обработать ее своевременно - надо знать точный размер этой порции в байтах. И висеть на чтении, пока необходимое количество байт не приедет. [Вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214630/373567) на базе протокола HTTP, учебная реализация. Я там читаю заголовки, из заголовка я узнаю вес тела пакета и читаю уже заранее известное количество байт в теле запроса. Насколько мне известно, данная проблема решается почти везде одинаково, и именно так.

Comment: В протоколе HTTP так же есть поддержка частичной передачи пакета - чанками, когда в заголовке нет явно указанной длины тела. Но там тоже после заголовка идет заголовок чанка, который указывает на смещение заголовка следующего чанка, прочитав следующий заголовок чанка процедура повторяется, и только в последнем чанке стоит флаг, что он последний и указатель на конец данных. То есть система посложнее, чем когда заранее известен вес всего пакета, но суть так же в том, что где хвост изестно до того, как он приедет. Возможно решение с чанками - то что вам нужно.

Comment: Вы ведь понимаете, что 0 в `bytes_read` вовсе не означает «все данные, которые посылал клиент, прочитаны»?

Comment: @VladD, да, вполне. Ноль означает, что больше нет данных для чтения. То есть клиент отослал все обращения, которые хотел.

Comment: @ShamusRezol: Это неверно. 0 означает «сервер не видит данных», а данные могут быть посланы клиентом и дойти через 5 минут. TCP — потоковый протокол, сервер не имеет никакой возможности знать, что кусок сообщения «окончен». https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html Похоже, ваш протокол ошибочен.