# TCP - Клиент(сервер) отправка и получения запросов и ответов без прерывания

Tags: c#, tcp

У меня есть клиент и сервер приложение, которое слушается на определённом порту.
Клиент посылает запрос, сервер принимает его и обрабатывает.
Я учусь только и хочу узнать несколько вещей:

1. - Как сделать сервер, чтобы он принимал много клиентов.
2. - На каких портах можно слушать клиентов?
3. - Сделать клиент-сервер без прерывания (сделать отдельный метод который будет закрывать соединения)

---

Вот мой **Клиент**:

Тут я пробую при подключение к серверу отправить какой-нибудь текст (который напишет пользователь)

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace TCPClient
{
    public static class ConnectServer
    {
       // private static readonly string ClientRequestString = "Some HTTP request here";
       // private static readonly byte[] ClientRequestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ClientRequestString);

        private const int PORT = 13400;

        public static async void ConnectAsTcpClient()
        {
            using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[Клиент] Подключение к серверу по порту: {PORT}");
                await tcpClient.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", PORT);
                Console.WriteLine("[Клиент] Подключение успешно");
                using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[Клиент] Написание запроса: ");
                    string text = Console.ReadLine();
                    await networkStream.WriteAsync(ClientRequestBytes(text), 0, ClientRequestBytes(text).Length);

                    var buffer = new byte[4096];
                    var byteCount = await networkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, byteCount);
                    Console.WriteLine($"[Клиент] Ответ сервера был {response}");
                }
            }
        }

        public static byte[] ClientRequestBytes(string data)
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Но он не отрабатывает, соединение закрывается.

Вот мой **Сервер**:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace TCPServer
{
    public static class ListenClient
    {
        private static readonly string ServerResponseString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><document><userkey>key</userkey> <machinemode>1</machinemode><serial>0000</serial><unitname>Device</unitname><version>1</version></document>\n";
        private static readonly byte[] ServerResponseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ServerResponseString);

        private const int PORT = 13400;

        public static async void StartListener()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[Сервер] слушаем клиента на порту: {PORT}");
            var tcpListener = TcpListener.Create(PORT);
            tcpListener.Start();

            var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"[Сервер] Подключился клиент: {tcpClient.Connected}");

            using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            {
                var buffer = new byte[4096];
                Console.WriteLine("[Сервер] Чтение от клиента");
                var byteCount = await networkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                var request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, byteCount);
                Console.WriteLine($"[Сервер] Клиент написал {request}");
                await networkStream.WriteAsync(ServerResponseBytes, 0, ServerResponseBytes.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("[Сервер] Ответ был написан");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того как я пишу какой-то текст в клиенте и отправляю, получаю ошибку а клиент закрывается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы же сами его закрываете используея конструкцию `using`...

Comment: @こきん, попробовал убрать `using` так же закрывается.

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214630/373567). Вам нужен цикл. И никогда не используйте `async void`.