# Синхронизация сервера и клиента по протоколу TCP

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient, tcplistener

Имеется сервер, организованный с помощью `TcpListener`, и клиент, организованный с помощью `TcpClient`. Данных от клиента серверу пересылается много, поэтому делается это построчно. Дело в том, что при пересылке сообщения от клиента к серверу последнему нужно некоторое время для обработки данных (вставляет данные из полученного сообщения в БД). Если поставить какой-нибудь примитивный `Thread.Sleep(1000)` перед каждым отправлением данных, то тогда сервер успевает за клиентом, но этот метод мне крайне не нравится. Как заставить их синхронизироваться друг с другом?

Comment: Сервер может присылать ответы о проделанной работе. И клиент либо ждать, либо дозировать нагрузку

Comment: @KoVadim ну, я для синхронизации придумал просто генерировать массив из одного байта со случайным значением элемента и отправлять его с клиента/сервера на сервер/клиент соответственно. Вроде как сработало.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214630/373567 просто надо отвечать на каждый запрос клиенту. А сервер должен параллельно и независимо обрабатывать все отдельные подключения. Посмотрите, как сделано в примере. Там конечно HTTP, но в эту же схему можно воткнуть любой протокол, в том числе и ваш. Ни в коем случае никаких `Thread.Sleep` делать не нужно.

Comment: А вообще возмите готовый HTTP сервер на базе ASP.NET Core Web API и не изобретайте велосипед. :) Освоить его не сложно, а работать с ним клиентом через класс `HttpClient` еще проще. Никаких проблем с синхронизациями там в принципе нет.

Comment: А зачем вам какая-то дополнительная синхронизация, если протокол TCP уже поддерживает управление потоком?

Comment: @PavelMayorov проблема в том, что иначе у меня сервер не успевал читать данные из потока из-за чего получалась рассинхронизация неприятная. А, учитывая тот факт, что у меня каждая строка шифруется с помощью RSA, то эта рассинхронизация просто недопустима.

Comment: @aepot я так и сделал по итогу. Выше написал, как. А что насчет готового HttpClient - проект учебный и преподаватель ограничил в использовании библиотек. Так что выбора особо не было.

Comment: @Blooderino погодите, а в чём эта самая "рассинхронизация" заключается? Так-то всё непрочитанное просто остаётся в очереди...

Comment: @PavelMayorov у меня данные передаются построчно. Строки при этом разного размера. Поэтому перед тем, как получать саму строку, я сделал отправку одного случайного байта с сервера на клиент перед тем как сам клиент начинает отправку очередную строку. Мне просто это нужно для того, чтобы кусок предыдущей строки не писался вместе с новой. Потому что без этой импровизированной синхронизации у меня происходит как раз то, что я описал.

Comment: Э-э-э, а что вам мешает просто читать на стороне сервера до перевода строки, а остаток оставлять на следующую строку? Зачем тут вообще синхронизация нужна, которая к тому же у вас слетает?

Comment: Синхронизация в том виде, в котором я уже реализовал на данный момент, работает исправно и ничего не слетает.

Answer (score -1):

1. Клиент посылает серверу пакет с сообщением. (используйте преимущественно json)
2. Сервер в `lock()` добавляет добавляет сообщение в `ConcurrentDictionary<long, string>`, но проверяя `long` на уникальность для `Dictionary`, `long` берётся на основе `DateTime.Now.Ticks` на стороне сервера, если `long` не уникален - делается `long++` пока не станет уникальным.
3. Сервер сразу отвечает клиенту что `long` принят и встал в очередь на обработку.
4. Клиент принимает `long` и заводит его в `List<long>` ожидающий подтверждения записи на стороне сервера.
5. Клиент в цикле по таймеру запрашивает у сервера `List<long>` ожидающих подтверждения записи.
6. Сервер так-же крутит в цикле свой `ConcurrentDictionary<long, string>` и если `Dictionary` не пустой - берёт сообщения и отправляет на запись в БД. Записанные сообщения удаляет из `Dictionary`.
7. Сервер при получении `List<long>` (пусть будет буфером) сверяет его с `ConcurrentDictionary<long, string>` внутри `lock()` и если в `Dictionary` нет `long` - удаляет его из `List<long>` буфера.
8. Сервер отвечает отфильтрованным `List<long>`, в котором будут содержаться только те `long`, которые ещё не были записаны в БД.
9. Клиент сравнивает исходный отправленный `List<long>` (не текущий, т.к. могли появиться ещё сообщения) и полученный `List<long>` от сервера (внимание `List<long>` должен быть пустой, а не null), после чего клиент удаляет записанные в БД `long` идентификаторы сообщений из текущего `List<long>`.

Это пример примитивной клиент-серверной архитектуры.
Достоинства:

- Придумана за 15 минут
- Примитивный
- Можно развивать!!! (в любом направлении)
- Можно очень просто сделать разные типы сообщений, не только текстовая строка
- Никто никого не ждёт (клиент не ждёт пока сервер запишет сообщение в БД)
- Есть система подтверждений о записи в БД (синхронизация, условно можно рисовать галочки как в Телеграм)
- Можно изменять принципы синхронизации как душе угодно, например выбросить `List<long>` и сделать что-то более надёжное и осмысленное, и так-же заменить `Dictionary<long, string>` на какой-нибудь более полноценный `Dictionary<id_struct, ICustomMessage>`
- Быстрая синхронизация, запрашивать можно хоть каждую 1/100 секунды, если ожидающих запись в БД сообщений не очень много
- Поддержка многопоточности на уровне концепта (вся работа с сервером может быть в отдельном потоке или по таймерам, ничего не сломается, но не нужно забывать что интерфейс клиента всегда должен обновляться через Invoke(), если у вас GUI на формах)

Недостатки:

- Придумана за 15 минут
- Забагованный (по любому есть косяки, например клиент пометит что сообщение записано в БД если сервер перезагрузится, это нужно лучше продумывать и вместо `List<long>` использовать какой-нибудь более надёжный подход)
- Требует продуманной системы сообщений (построчно писать не получится, хотя тем-же json'ом можно и в одну строку, но лучше так не делать)

Comment: Я бы еще сказал, что эта концепция больше для UDP подходит, чем для TCP.

Comment: @aepot c UDP конечно будет лучше, но и с TCP никаких проблем нет.