# Создание локального прокси-сервера на C#

Tags: c#, прокси, трафик

Задача заключается в фильтрации HTTP трафика, исходя из определенных правил. Я решил создать локальный прокси-сервер на C#, в настройках сети Windows также включить прокси.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        Console.WriteLine(isOn());
        
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080); // слушаем соединение
        listener.Start();
        while (true) 
        {
            var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => RecvData(client)); // и когда нам приходит запрос на подключение создаем новый поток
            thread.Start();
        }
    }

    public static void RecvData(TcpClient client) 
    {
        NetworkStream browser = client.GetStream();
        byte[] buf;
        buf = new byte[16000];
        while (true) // здесь мы читаем данные которые отправляет нам браузер и передаем их на обработку в httpserv
        {
            if (!browser.CanRead)
                return;
            try
            {
                browser.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                return;
            }
            HTTPserv(buf, browser, client);
        }
    }

    public static void HTTPserv(byte[] buf, NetworkStream browser, TcpClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] temp = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf).Trim().Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });
            
            string req = temp.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("Host")); 
            req = req.Substring(req.IndexOf(":") + 2);
            string[] port = req.Trim().Split(new char[] { ':' }); // получаем имя домена и номер порта (если есть)

            TcpClient server;
            if (port.Length == 2) // тут мы соединяемся с сервером по имени хоста и если есть порт в запросе то по порту, а если нет то по стандартному 80
            {
                server = new TcpClient(port[0], int.Parse(port[1]));
            }
            else
            {
                server = new TcpClient(port[0], 80);
            }

            NetworkStream servStream = server.GetStream(); // поток с сервером
            servStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length); // отправляем данные на сервер, которые получили от браузера
            var respBuf = new byte[32]; // для заголовка
            
           
            servStream.Read(respBuf, 0, respBuf.Length); // ответ от сервера

            browser.Write(respBuf, 0, respBuf.Length); // отправляем этот ответ браузеру

            string[] head = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(respBuf).Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }); // получаем код ответа
     
            string ResponseCode = head[0].Substring(head[0].IndexOf(" ") + 1);
            Console.WriteLine(req, " ", ResponseCode);
            servStream.CopyTo(browser); // перенаправляем остальные данные от сервера к браузеру

        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Close();
        }

    }
```

Выше представлен фрагмент кода самого сервера. На данный момент он должен просто логгировать запросы, но этого не происходит. Проблема, если я правильно понял, заключается в том, что сервер сам не может отправить запрос из-за системных настроек прокси. Каким образом можно пропускать сетевой трафик через локальный прокси-сервер и либо передавать запросы хосту, либо отклонять их? Возможно есть другой, более простой способ решения поставленной задачи?

Comment: а куда отправляется запрос из браузера? по HTTP или HTTPS? ваш сервер слегка странно сделан. Вот [рабочий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214630/373567). HTTP сервера, прикрутите туда переадресацию запросов и получится локальный прокси. А вообще ALG есть на почти любом современно роутере, там же можно и логирование прикрутить безо всяких прокси. Для такой задачи на самом деле снифать TCP трафик проще, чем проксировать.

Comment: Запрос из браузера с помощью настроек windows отправляется на 127.0.0.1:8080 (т.е. на локальный прокси-сервер). Прокси-сервер должен отправлять его на удаленный хост. Конечное решение должно поддерживать HTTPS, но сейчас разобраться бы хотя бы с HTTP. В итоге мне просто нужно будет в каждом запросе получать хост на который отправляется запрос и решать, пропустить его или отклонить. Я могу ошибаться в каких-либо терминах, так как только начинаю изучать сетевое программирование, поэтому если где-то я пишу бред, скажите мне об этом, пожалуйста, постараюсь объяснить по-другому

Comment: Можно использовать WireShark с логированием в файл и следить за тем что оно пишет. Нужный вам софт уже существует, грубо говоря. Смысл задачи сильно зависит от того, надо вам блочить часть трафика, или не надо, а просто отслеживать.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, буду смотреть ваш пример. Сам проект мне нужен не для конкретных целей, а просто для изучения данной темы, поэтому готовый софт меня не интересует. Часть трафика надо будет блочить

Comment: Грубо говоря, я делаю аналог BurpSuite, только с автоматической обработкой запросов

Comment: Ну тогда почти готовый HTTP сервер я вам уже дал. Осталось научиться отправлять запросы дальше. Обязательно изучите async/await, без них с сетью работать крайне неудобно.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Тогда еще вопрос, мне для того, чтобы прогнать трафик через программу необходимо указать локальный прокси в настройках системы. А когда сам локальный сервер будет пытаться передать запрос дальше, он не будет из-за тех же настроек передавать запрос обратно себе?

Comment: Браузер по своей воле читает эти настройки и использует. В вашем случае Хром, верно? Потому ФФ их не читает и не использует, у нее свои настройки. Эти настройки на низком уровне не существуют. Грубо говоря, если в программе они вам нужны, вы должны сами залезть в реестр и оттуда их забрать и использовать. Еще замечу, что протокол HTTP Proxy отличается от голого HTTP, поэтому изучайте, дорабатывайте парсер пакетов.