# Как правильно остановить BinaryReader ReadChar?

Tags: c#, потоки-данных

Имею такой код

```
using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
using (cancellationToken.Register(() =>
{
    try { stream.Dispose(); }
    catch { }
}))
{
    while (true)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var messageHeader = ReadMessageHeader(reader);
...
}

private static MessageHeader ReadMessageHeader(BinaryReader streamReader)
{
    var messageHeader = new MessageHeader();

    while (true)
    {
        var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
...
}

public static string ReadLine(this BinaryReader reader)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    bool foundEndOfLine = false;
    char ch;
    while (!foundEndOfLine)
    {
        try
        {
            ch = reader.ReadChar();
...
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, кусок кода

```
using (cancellationToken.Register(() =>
{
    try { stream.Dispose(); }
    catch { }
}))
```

сделан именно для того, чтобы грохнуть поток и закончить чтение, поскольку `ReadChar()` может находиться в состоянии ожидания, если данные в поток не поступают.

Проблема такого подхода в том, что бросается исключение IOException.

Если платформа NetFramework 4.8, то InnerExseption SocketErrorCode содержит в себе `System.Net.Sockets.SocketError.Interrupted Не удается прочитать данные из транспортного соединения: Операция блокирования прервана вызовом WSACancelBlockingCall`,

а на NET5 содержит `System.Net.Sockets.SocketError.OperationAborted Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение`

Как правильно остановить процесс чтения из потока?

Comment: Так и останавливайте. В чём проблема поймать исключение?

Comment: Ловите исключение и проверяете cancellationToken - если он отменен, значит задача была отменена юзером и исключение нужно подавить.

Comment: А что этот код делает? Читает ответ из `HttpClient`? Почему бы вам просто не прочитаетьь его в строку или в массив байт, а потом работать с полученными данными без вот этих вот костылей? `byte[] data = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();` либо если там только текст, то `ReadAsStringAsync()` сгодится. И я бы предложил забыть про Framework 4.x, это устаревший фреймворк.

Comment: @aepot в том то и проблема, что перешли на net и появились проблемы. Раньше отлавливалось исключение с фильтром по Interrupted, а теперь не отлавливается. И я не уверен, что правильно отлавливать с фильтром по OperationAborted. Там что-то нечто подписки на события от сервера, для того что бы получать их сколь угодно долго. Типа SignalR. Пока не решусь тут переделывать. Попробую сделать, как предложил `vitidev`

Comment: Так WebSocket же есть. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1248356/373567, вот еще полезного кода вам https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214630/373567. Уходите от костылей, вы ломаете протокол при наличии готовых решений. Тот же SignalR есть, чем не решение?

Comment: @aepot изучу. Код 2017 года, писал не я. Легаси

Comment: @dmitriy BinaryReader может иметь встроенный буфер, поэтому разделить пакеты при получении данных пачками, а не попакетно, может не получиться, потому что старый ридер может захватить себе кусок новых данных и обвалить всю логику. В ссылке про TcpListener посмотрите на метод `private string ReadLine()`, он кстати, с небольшими изменениями, стырен из недр дотнета, я не с нуля его придумывал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что в .NET 5 изменилось исключение - это нормально. Дело в том, что под капотом `HttpClient` в Framework 4.x лежит `WebRequestHandler`, а в .NET Core 3/.NET 5 и новее - `SocketsHttpHandler`, использующий более современный, с нуля переписанный HTTP движок.

Поэтому исключения в каких-то местах могут быть разные. Просто перепишите код под новые отладочные данные.

---

Можно конечно `WebRequestHandler` насильно запихнуть в `HttpClient` и получать исключения по-старому, но я бы не советовал вам этого делать, так как старый HTTP движок значительно хуже по эффективности, чем новый и много всего не поддерживает в условиях современного интернета.