# Принцип работы прокси-сервера при взаимодействии с браузером

Tags: c#, proxy, браузер, прокси

пишу прокси-сервер, который взаимодействует с трафиком браузера. Не хочу тупо копипастить код серверов, а хочу понять, как это всё работает в теоретическом плане. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто может, как должен работать прокси-сервер с браузером, что он должен делать, когда обрабатывает пакеты браузера, что он должен делать, чтобы нормально отображались страницы браузера, а не ошибка прокси-сервера. Буду очень признателен

Comment: Читайте RFC 7230 в частности разделы, относящиеся к прокси-серверам и другим intermediaries: 2.3 Connection, 2.7 Uniform Resource Identifiers, 3 Message Format, 5 Request, 6 Response и особенно 9 Connection Management и 6.1 Request/Response Chain

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA я ему же [предлагал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1508932/373567) почитать RFC, даже [готовое решение](https://github.com/justcoding121/titanium-web-proxy) предлагал поизучать или использовать, но видимо здесь вопрос про то как написать прокси не читая спеки, полный игнор предложенных к изучению материалов.